# Qual a finalidade da @Override?

Tags: java

Estou com algumas dúvidas quanto ao `@override`, li em algum lugar e me lembro vagamente sobre a questão da reescrita, mas o que é isso? E para que serve? Como se aplica em um código **JAVA**. Existe em alguma outra linguagem?

Comment: http://www.k19.com.br/artigos/para-que-serve-a-anotacao-override-da-linguagem-java/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Ele é uma forma de garantir que você está sobrescrevendo um método e não criando um novo.

Vamos supor que você criou uma classe com um método de imprimir:

```
public class SuperClasse {
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("imprime");
    }
}
```

Daí você fez uma classe que estende essa classe, e você quer mudar o que será impresso quando o método for chamado:

```
public class MinhaClasse extends SuperClasse {
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("imprime diferente");
    }
}
```

Você sobrescreveu corretamente o método `imprime()` e o código acima funcionará sem maiores problemas.

Entretanto um belo dia você resolveu mudar o nome do método na SuperClasse de `imprime()` para `imprimir()`:

```
public class SuperClasse {
    public void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("imprime");
    }
}
```

Se você não se lembrar da classe que estendeu a SuperClasse você terá um método `imprime()` nela que **não está sobrescrevendo o método na SuperClasse**. Você na verdade está chamando um método novo, que se chama `imprime()`.

### O que aconteceria se você tivesse usado o annotation @Override ?

Esse seria seu código a princípio para as duas classes:

```
public class SuperClasse {
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("imprime");
    }
}

public class MinhaClasse extends SuperClasse {
    @Override
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("imprime diferente");
    }
}
```

Até o momento, nada de novo. Entretanto quando você alterar o seu método de `imprime()` para  `imprimir()` você não mais conseguirá compilar seu código pois o @Override perceberá que você não está sobrescrevendo coisa nenhuma, pois não existe mais nenhum método `imprime()` na SuperClasse.

Você receberá o seguinte erro:

> MinhaClasse must override or implement a supertype method

Em tradução (bem) livre:

> MinhaClasse deve sobrescrever ou implementar um método da sua super classe

Toda linguagem orientada a objetos permite a sobrescrita de métodos da super classe pela classe filha. Entretanto cada linguagem de programação usa seus próprios meios para lidar com essa sobrescrita. O Java optou por usar o annotation @Override para os desenvolvedores que quiserem a segurança citada no decorrer da resposta, entretanto, nada obriga o uso desse annotation.

O C# também possui tal funcionalidade, entretanto ele não usa annotation, ele incorpora a palavra reservada `override` na declaração do método:

```
public override int Area()
{
    return side * side;
}
```

É impossível listar todas as linguagens de programação que fazem uso do `override` pois acredite se quiser, existem milhares (literalmente!) de linguagens por aí. Se quiser uma lista um pouco mais completa veja: [Wikipedia - Method overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)

Comment: Que resposta incrível, parabéns pelo grande conhecimento compartilhado!

Answer (score 19):

***O que é*** `Override` ***em Programação Orientada a Objeto?***

Reescrever um método que foi herdado, aonde seu comportamento na classe Pai, se difere do seu comportamento na classe filha. Ou seja, eles possuem o mesmo nome, mas, funcionalidades ou ações diferentes. ***Obs:*** *Se você não reescrever o método ele terá o comportamento da classe Pai, que pela lógica só há uma implementação*.

***Existe em outras linguagens?***

Nas linguagens Orientadas a Objeto, isso é um fator trivial, existem nelas talvez o que mude é a sua forma de implementação.

***Exemplo:***

```
public class Pai {    
    public int Soma(int value){
        return value + 100;
    }
}

public class Filho extends Pai {
    @Override
    public int Soma(int value){
        return value + 200;
    }
}
```

***Codificação***

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Pai pai = new Pai();
    System.out.println(pai.Soma(1));
        
    Filho filho = new Filho();        
    System.out.println(filho.Soma(1));
}
```

***Resultado***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Perceba que na classe Pai o valor é um e na classe Filha é outra, ou seja, como foi reescrito, você pode ter comportamentos diferentes nas classes***

Answer (score 15):

## Sobrescrita ou *Override*

A sobrescrita de um método ocorre quando uma classe filha implementa um método que já existe numa classe mãe, alterando (sobrescrevendo) o comportamento existente.

Exemplo:

```java
public class Gato {
    public void falar() {
        System.out.println("Miau");
    }
}

public class Gatinho extends Gato {
    public void falar() {
        System.out.println("Mew");
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, a classe `Gatinho` herda a classe `Gato`, porém muda o comportamento do método `falar()`.

Se chamarmos os métodos polimorficamente, o resultado é diferente. Exemplo:

```java
Gato gato = new Gato();
gato.falar();
Gatinho gatinho = new Gatinho();
gatinho.falar();
Gato gatoPolimorfico = new Gatinho();
gatoPolimorfico.falar();
```

O resultado será:

> Miau
>
> Mew
>
> Mew

## Classe `java.lang.Object`

Especificamente na linguagem Java, existe a classe `Object` que é mãe de todas as outras classes. Isso significa que, mesmo não tendo um `extends` na declaração, toda classe possui uma herança implícita.

A classe `Object` possui alguns métodos especiais. Um deles é o `toString()`, usado para "representar" um objeto em forma de `String`. Nesse caso, poderíamos *sobrescrever* o método mesmo sem ter uma herança explícita.

Exemplo:

```java
public class Gato {
    public String toString() {
        return "Sou um Gato";
    }
}
```

## Assinaturas dos métodos sobrescritos

Existe um detalhe da sobrescrita de métodos que não foi mencionada e causa problemas frequentemente: **para sobrescrever um método, você deve manter exatamente a mesma assinatura**.

O que é uma assinatura na linguagem Java? É a composição dos elementos que declaram o método.

Considere a seguinte assinatura:

```java
public String setNome(String nome) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Agora considere os elementos que fazem parte da declaração de um método:

- **Modificadores de acesso**: `public`, `private`, `protected`
- **Outros modificadores**: `static`, `native`, `synchronized`
- **Tipo de Retorno**: `String`, `int`
- **Nome do método**: `setNome`
- **Tipos e nomes de Parâmetros**: `String nome`
- **Exceções declaradas**: `IllegalArgumentException`

Especificamente em Java, a sobrescrita de métodos ocorre se pelo menos o nome e os tipos dos parâmetros forem iguais.

O exemplo a seguir descreve uma **sobrecarga** (*overload*) de método e não uma sobrescrita:

```java
public class OutroGatinho extends Gato {
    public void falar(String frase) {
        System.out.println(frase);
    }
}
```

Na classe acima, considerando o primeiro exemplo, o método `falar(String)` **não** está sobrescrevendo o método `falar()` da classe `Gato`, porque a assinatura é diferente.

Outra característica da linguagem Java é ela diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas (*case sensitive*). Isso pode levar a equívocos, como o exemplo a seguir:

```java
public class Gato {
    public String tostring() {
        return "Sou um Gato";
    }
}
```

Note que o `s` está minúsculo em `tostring`. Isso faz com que o método acima não seja chamado como o se esperava!

## Anotação `@Override` ao resgate!

Então veio a anotação `@Override`. Ela simplesmente informa ao compilador que a **intenção** seria de sobrescrever.

Dessa forma, o compilador pode avaliar se a assinatura está coerente com algum método das superclasses e **emite um aviso** caso o método não esteja realmente sobrescrevendo algo!

Então, no exemplo do `tostring` minúsculo, ficaria evidente ao desenvolvedor que houve algum equívoco.

Além disso, é comum quando o código de um sistema é modificado ou bibliotecas são atualizadas, ocorrer de métodos que o desenvolvedor sobrescreveu simplesmente deixarem de ser chamados sem aviso. Isso porque um método de uma classe sobrescrita foi alterado ou removido. Com a anotação `@Override`, você fica mais "seguro" para fazer esse tipo de mudança e poder rastrear os pontos do código que precisam de atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Sobrescrever ( sobrecarregar ) métodos faz parte da orientação a objeto que não entrarei em detalhes, já que a pergunta é voltada a anotação.

A anotação serve, basicamente, para "avisar" ao compilador que aquele método está sobrescrevendo ( *overriding* ) um método da superclasse da qual ele estende.

Comment: Sobrescrever e sobrecarregar são coisas distintas, não!?

Comment: Essa resposta está meio confusa.