# @Override é obrigatório em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Se eu tenho uma classe abstrata `Pessoa` com um método abstrato `lerNome` quando eu estou implementando esse método na minha classe `João` eu devo fazer o uso da `@Override` em `lerNome`? O mesmo acontece quando eu uso interfaces?

Comment: Não é uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22913/qual-a-finalidade-da-override?

Comment: Não lembrava que existia esta outra pergunta. Ela é certamente sobre o mesmo assunto porém mais abrangente. **Não sei** se é exatamente uma duplicata, pode ser que sim. Vejamos o que outras pessoas pensam.

Comment: É, eu vi que ela é mais abrangente, se não for duplicata acho legal ele dar uma lida pra se aprofundar melhor.

Comment: Não creio que seja duplicata. Inclusive a resposta escolhida à pergunta linkada está incompleta pois trata a anotação `@override`apenas como um recuro para evitar erros, o que não é o caso.

Comment: @Caffé, Hã?!? Que eu saiba é só um recurso para evitar erros... Se puder indicar a fonte dessa informação eu quero ler, porque eu não sabia disso...

Comment: @Wakim O que misturei foi Java com C#. Em C# você tem a opção de esconder ou de fato sobrescrever o método da classe pai, e sobrescrever só é possível se o método for declarado como Virtual. Se você não sobrescrever explicitamente, você está apenas escondendo, e você pode ainda usar uma declaração explícita para esconder. Enquando em C# os métodos são selados por padrão, em Java todos os métodos são virtuais por padrão - e essa parte do Java eu não sabia até agora!

Comment: @Caffé, há tudo bem, não sabia que o C# tinha esse comportamento, não conheço a fundo. Obrigado por explicar, desculpe qualquer coisa :)

Comment: @user11504 se alguma resposta respondeu o que você queria, você pode marcá-la como aceita. Veja como em [tour].

Answer (score 25):

Sim, você usã-lo para o compilador fazer a checagem e evitar que esteja sobrescrevendo o método errado (talvez com a assinatura errada), "[escondendo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)" o método correto e possivelmente chamando o método na classe errada. Com ele você evita o equívoco por um erro de digitação, por exemplo. Usando você receberá um *warning* indicando o problema.

Como é "apenas" um *warning* **não há obrigatoriedade** de resolver o problema de fato para que o programa compile, mas como sempre deve-se considerar *warnings* como se fossem erros, digamos que é "moralmente" obrigatório. De qualquer forma fica mais fácil manter um código com a informação explícita que sua intenção é sobrescrever o método.

Isso vale para métodos declarados em interfaces também.

Mais informações sobre o porquê desta anotação existir e como ela funciona podem ser obtidas [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Tanto em classes que implementam os métodos de uma interface como em subclasses que subscrevem métodos em superclasses, esta anotação **não é obrigatória**, porém ela informa ao compilador que o método "anotado" subscreve um método da sua superclasse (incluindo interfaces).

Referência(muito objectiva):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 3):

É recomendada, **não obrigatória**, até porque se você trabalhar com `JREs` legado como a `1.4` ou anteriores, não existem anotações, então nesse caso você não deve usar @Override, é só uma convenção para facilitar a identificação de métodos sobrescritos, nada mais.