# Qual é a função do @Override em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Vendo alguns código ou mesmo criar um método automático notei a presença dele `@Override`.
O que realmente ele faz no código?

Comment: @Marconi mal posso ver seus movimentos!

Comment: @DiegoF rs, Pesquisa simples no google, já acha ela.

Comment: Também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A anotação @Override explicita que o método declarado está sobrescrevendo um método de mesma assinatura declarado na superclasse ou na interface que está sendo estendida/implementada pela sua classe.