# Pode-se fazer override em construtores?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

É possível realizar override em construtores? 
Por exemplo:

```
@Override
public class main (String arg[]){}
```

Comment: Olá @Dr.G, primeiramente quero apresentar algumas áreas do site e recomendo fortemente que leia e conheça antes de fazer perguntas e qualquer coisa. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) no Stack e saiba [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: É uma pergunta já respondida? Quando você estende uma classe, você deve definir um novo construtor, não tem como sobrescrever o construtor da classe estendida, pois ele não é o construtor do objeto atual. Se a linguagem permitir(nunca testei isso), que você reescreva(defina um método com o nome da classe estendida, duvido que este seja invocado quando você der new no objeto.

Comment: @VictorGomes é só de mim ou a pergunta é suficientemente boa para estar no site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da maneira como está tentando fazer como se o construtor fosse um método não é possível. Um construtor não é polimórfico e a herança se dá de outra forma.

Pode-se dizer que há um relação de herança entre o construtor da classe base e a classe derivada, afinal o construtor da classe derivada assume o papel principal de construção e depois delega implícita ou explicitamente a construção da base.

De qualquer forma isto não ocorrerá no método `main()` que não é construtor de nenhuma classe. Pelo menos ao que dá para entender. E se a intenção era criar um método na pergunta, a sintaxe está toda errada.

Lembrando que o [`@Override` não é obrigatório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101).

```
class Base {
    Base() {
        System.out.println("Construção Base");
        metodo();
    }
    void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Método em Base");
    }
}

class Derivada extends Base {
    Derivada() {
        System.out.println("Construção Derivada");
    }
    @Override
    void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Método em Derivada");
    }
}

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Base base = new Base();
        base.metodo();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        Derivada derivada = new Derivada();
        derivada.metodo();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/x7Bmyc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kpqlyrha-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/OverrideConstructor.java).