# Sobrescrita de método vale para toda hierarquia de classes?

Tags: java, polimorfismo, sobrescrita

Quando tem vários `extends` (como no exemplo abaixo) todos os métodos são sobrescritos até o último `extends`? Se não, qual método que vai ser utilizado?

```
class D extends C {
  void x() {
    System.out.println(1);
  }

}
class C extends B {
  void x() {
    System.out.println(2);
  }

}
class B {
  void x() {
    System.out.println(3);
  }
  void y(B b) {
    b.x();

  }
  void y(C c) {
    c.x();

  }
  void y(D d) {
    d.x();

  }

}
class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B().y(new C());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se entendi o que quer saber, mas já adianto que nenhuma classe é sobrescrita, esta não é uma qualidade que classes possuem. Métodos podem ser sobrescritos.

E sim, todos os métodos tradicionais em Java que são virtuais são sobrescritos não importa a profundidade da hierarquia e eles substituem o método das classes mães, portanto este código irá imprimir `2`.

E portanto a classe que será usada é aquela que for instanciada em determinado local, a escolha de classes é feita pelo programador. Em nenhum momento neste código ocorre [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101), por isso neste caso também não há escolha de métodos, é usado o método da classes sendo usado de forma pura e simples.

E as sobrescritas idealmente deveriam usar a [anotação `@Override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101).

Comment: Vlw amigo, ficou bem claro, escrevi errado era métodos mesmo. Para eu ter certeza se entendi, se por ventura eu escrevesse "new B().x()" ao invés de "new B().y(new C())" executaria o polimorfismo e retornaria "1"?

Comment: Este código não tem polimorfismo em parte alguma, muito menos nesta parte, mas resultaria em 1 de forma simples e direta.

Comment: não tem sobrescrita?

Comment: Não tem polimorfismo.

Comment: Blz vlw por tudo, me ajudou bastante, preciso procurar entender melhor o termo polimorfismo.

Comment: Por isso eu coloquei um link na resposta.