# Estender x Sobrescrita, qual a diferença?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Pesquisando sobre conceitos de Orientação a Objetos, me deparei com o seguinte comparativo, Estender (Herança) versus Sobrescrita.

Encontrei a seguinte afirmação para esse comparativo:

**Estender:**

*Quando incluímos novos atributos, métodos em uma classe filha.*

**Sobrescrever**

*Se redefinirmos métodos já existentes (herdados) em uma classe filha*

Esta definição não ficou clara na minha visão. Qual a diferença entre Estender e Sobrescrita em Orientação a Objetos?

Comment: Quando for colocar alguma informação externa tenha certeza que podemos acessá-la facilmente. Caso contrário é irrelevante dizer onde pegou. Pode até ficar parecendo *spam*, mesmo que não seja sua intenção. Lembrando que a maioria dos cursos na internet, pagos ou gratuitos, ensinam só o básico e muitas vezes de forma errada. Em geral, nenhum vale a pena. a não ser para uma introdução. Isto se tiver senso crítico. Se confiar nos cursos, tá lascado.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelo seu feedback @bigown. Vou editar minha pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Estender (`extend`) é um conceito da classe e mais amplo. Você estende uma classe provavelmente colocando novos membros (não só atributos) dentro dela ou fazendo algo a mais nos métodos já existentes. Sempre que criamos uma classe herdando de outro temos a intenção de estender a classe de alguma forma.

Sobrescrever (`override`) é um conceito do método e mais específico. Você sobrescreve um método existente em uma classe herdada, ou seja, você faz a implementação contida no método da classe atual ser usada no lugar da implementação existente na classe herdada. Algumas linguagens fazem isso de forma implícita e outras exigem que seja explicitado o desejo de sobrescrita, já que, de outra forma, a sobrescrita poderia acontecer por acidente, sem o desejo do programador.

Veja o exemplo em linguagem fictícia (as regras de cada linguagem podem variar):

```
class A {
    metodo1() { print "A"; }
    metodo2() { print "A"; }
}

class B extends A {
    override metodo1() { print "B"; }
    metodo2() { print "B"; }
}

A a = new A().metodo1(); //imprime A
A b = new B().metodo1(); //imprime B, note que o tipo é A, mas a implementação é B
A c = new B().metodo2(); //imprime A, o tipo é A e o método não foi sobrescrito
```

[Leia mais sobre o `override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/101) e [sua opcionalidade no Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101).

Um adendo: fiz um teste com Java e C#. Eu sabia como a segunda se comportava mas não tinha certeza da primeira.

O exemplo acima funciona bem para C#. Faz o que eu disse e dá um *warning* que provavelmente não é o que você quer.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ehqF7j). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/teSNrs). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Override.cs).

O Java fez o *override* mesmo não podendo.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rVGrbw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bifvskdm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Override.java).

Mas a resposta ainda vale. É que agora eu sei que o Java faz o `override` implícito até onde não deveria. tenha isto em mente quando for programar em Java.

Comment: Fiquei com uma dúvida, nas linhas A b = new B().metodo2(); e A c = new B().metodo2(); ambos não deveriam imprimir "B"? Porque b e c não apontam para um objeto de B, cujo metodo2() printa "B"? Fiquei confuso com os comentários das linhas

Comment: Oops. Tinha um erro de digitação. Os comentários estão certos. Só note que o `c` em Java, vai imprimir `B`, o que eu considero um erro da linguagem. Aprenda conviver com isto se continuar programando em Java. Isto não é *overriding* , isto é *shadowing*. Parece ser a mesma coisa, mas quase nunca o programador quer sombrear o método da classe mãe. E é mais grave porque mesmo que você diga que o método não pode ser sobrescrito, a linguagem faz algo que dá resultado semelhante.

Comment: Entendi, agora vi sua edição. Em Java a anotação @Override é opcional, então eu achei um pouco estranho isso quando li a respeito. Muito obrigado!

Comment: É, o Java faz `override` queira você ou não.

Comment: Na verdade Java nunca faz *shadowing* (ou *"hiding"* ou *"reintroduce"*) de um método de instância; ao contrário, o **Java sempre faz override**. De modo que também "não querer override" em Java não faz muito sentido. Se o recurso de *hiding* é tão importante (e na minha opinião é completamente dispensável em um bom design, bem como a própria herança na maioria das vezes também é dispensável), basta usar uma linguagem que suporte. Por fim, querendo mesmo o comportamento de *shadowing* em Java, na prática você o terá sempre que na classe filha você deixar de invocar o método da classe pai.

Comment: @Caffé É verdade, me confundi nos termos usados. Mas a resposta não está errada. Mas nem vale à pena discutir com você. Você gosta de negativar porque tem uma vírgula errada.

Comment: Então imagino que você concorde com a minha edição retirando a informação equivocada, de modo que não há mais motivo para negativar.

Comment: @Caffé está ok.

Answer (score 4):

Quando usa herança a classe que recebe automaticamente possui os mesmos métodos e atributos.

Em alguns casos você necessita mudar o método da classe que está estendendo. O exemplo abaixo demonstra essa diferença. A pessoa possui apenas dois atributos, logo para retornar os dados posso retornar apenas nome e cpf. Já no caso do Funcionario além de nome cpf, será necessário retornar o salário por isso será necessário reescrever o método. Por isso usamos o "@Override" para indicar que naquela classe o método "getDados" deve ter um comportamento especifico.

```
class Pessoa {

    protected String nome;
    protected String cpf;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String cpf){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getCpf(){
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf){
        this.cpf = cpf
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDados(){
        return cpf + "-" + nome;
    }
}

class Funcionario extends Pessoa /* Estende a classe Pessoa */{

    protected double salario;

    public Funcionario(String nome, String cpf, double salario){
        super(nome, cpf); /* Chama o método construtor da classe Pessoa */
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public double getSalario(){
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario){
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    @Override /* Sobrescreve o método da classe pessoa, dessa forma irá rodar o método da classe Funcionário */
    public String getDados(){
        return cpf + "-" + nome + "-" + salario;
    }
}

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Pessoa("Joao Maria", "987.456.777-45").getDados()); // Display the string.
        System.out.println(new Funcionario("Joao Carlos", "456.222.444-33", 1256.00).getDados());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Estender

Quando você estende uma classe (abstrata ou não), você está fazendo com que a nova classe tenha todos os métodos e atributos da classe que você está estendendo.
Se você estender a classe abaixo

```
class Animal{
    String raca;

    public String getRaca(){
        return raca;
    }
}
```

numa classe chamada `Gato`, a sua nova classe terá o atributo `raca` e o método `getRaca()` já implementados.

> Sobrescrever

Porém, na sua classe `Gato`, você poderá sobrescrever o método `getRaca`, fazendo com que ele tenha outro comportamento, ou até mesmo, que ele tenha algum código adicionado. Veja o exemplo

```
class Gato extends Animal{
    public string getRaca(){
        return "Raça qualquer"; //Aqui eu estou sobrescrevendo o comportamento do método
    }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal{
    public String getRaca(){
        String base = super.getRaca(); //Aqui estou usando o método da "classe pai"
        return "Cachorro: " + base; //Aqui o retorno da classe filha
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Exemplos:

Estender:

```
class Pessoa {

    String nome;

    setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome }
    getNome() { return this.nome }  
}

class Funcionario extends Pessoa {

    /* Método getPis() ou setPis(String pis) são novos métodos da 
     *  classe Funcionário sendo que a mesma é filha da classe Pessoa      
     */

    String pis;

    setPis(String pis){ this.pis = pis }
    getPis() { return this.pis }  
}
```

Sobrescrever:

```
class Pessoa {

    String nome;

    setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome }
    getNome() { return this.nome }  
}

class Funcionario extends Pessoa {

    String pis;

    setPis(String pis){ this.pis = pis }
    getPis() { return this.pis } 

    /* Aqui estamos sobrescrevendo um método que existe na classe
     * pai da classe Pessoa passando um valor padrão para o atributo nome
     * diferente do método setNome da classe pai
     */ 

    @Override
    setNome(String nome) { this.nome = "Sou tratado de forma diferente" }
}
```