# Quais as diferenças entre os conceitos de polimorfismo e sobrescrita em OOP?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, polimorfismo

Fiquei um pouco confuso ao pesquisar sobre polimorfismo. O conceito de polimorfismo assemelha-se ao conceito de sobrescrita. Quais as diferenças entre polimorfismo e sobrescrita em OOP?

Comment: Em poucas palavras: **Polimorfismo** é a capacidade de um objeto de assumir diversas formas, de modo que um objeto **X**, se polimórfico, poderia assumir por exemplo a forma do objeto **Y**. Uma das maneiras de implementar polimorfismo é através da herança. **Sobrescrita** é a capacidade de um objeto de oferecer uma implementação para um comportamento do objeto cuja forma ele assumiu. Assim, se X herda Y e sobrescreve um comportamento de Y, quando X assumir a forma de Y (for usado num lugar onde Y era esperado) e o tal comportamento for invocado, será executada a implementação de X e não de Y.

Comment: @Caffé, boa respota

Answer (score 11, accepted):

São coisas relacionadas. A sobrescrita é usada para alcançar o polimorfismo. Não é o único mecanismo mas é o mais usado na maioria das linguagens *mainstream*.

O polimorfismo é a característica que pode usar um objeto no lugar de outro como se fosse o objeto esperado. Para isto funcionar direito é necessário que o mecanismo exista para garantir que está acessado os membros corretos.

Uma situação comum é esperar um objeto e receber um outro que é descendente deste esperado. Se chamar um método deste objeto, ele vai chamar o método do objeto esperado ou do objeto concreto descendente que foi recebido?

Sem a sobrescrita, ele iria chamar o método do objeto esperado, do pai. Mas em geral não é o que se deseja. A sobrescrita informa que este método do objeto filho deve ser usado no lugar e atende ao requisito do polimorfismo.

Evidentemente que há casos em que não se deseja esta substituição, não se quer o polimorfismo em situação específica. Aí a sobrescrita não deve ser utilizada. Algumas linguagens lidam melhor com isto do que outras.

Em uma [pergunta sobre o tema eu falo sobre como pode funciona o mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101) usando o exemplo de linguagens que não possuem o polimorfismo nativamente.

Usando o [exemplo já dado em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89223/101) (linguagem fictícia) veja como funciona o polimorfismo:

```all
class A {
    metodo1() { print "A"; }
    metodo2() { print "A"; }
}

class B extends A {
    override metodo1() { print "B"; }
    metodo2() { print "B"; }
}

void executa(A obj) { //note que ele receberá sempre algo do tipo A
    obj.metodo1();
    obj.metodo2();
}

executa(new A()); //imprime A e A
executa(new B()); //imprime B e A
```

O primeiro exemplo não ocorre polimorfismo. O objeto esperado deve ser do tipo `A` e realmente é o que é enviado.

O segundo exemplo ocorre polimorfismo no `metodo1()`. Foi enviado um objeto do tipo `B` para um método que esperava receber algo do tipo `A`. Isto é possível porque o tipo `B` deriva de `A`, ou seja atende todos os requisitos de `A`. Como o método foi sobrescrito, ele chamará a versão do objeto concreto, ou seja de `B`.

Mas no `metodo2()` o polimorfismo não ocorre porque não houve a sobrescrita. Então como o método `executa()` espera algo do tipo `A` ele vai procurar em `A` mesmo o que executar. Ele não assumiu outra forma.

A forma mais comum de realizar isto internamente na linguagem é através de uma tabela de ponteiros para os métodos (*vtable*). Quando há a sobrescrita, o endereço do método da classe derivada é usado no lugar do endereço do método original. Quando for feita uma chamada deste método, ao invés de ele simplesmente chamar o método por seu endereço conhecido, ele vai procurar nessa tabela qual é o endereço a ser chamado.

Um exemplo mais concreto usando classe abstrata seria criar um manipulador de *log*. Claro que isto não faz uso de "boas práticas", é uma forma simplificada:

```all
abstract class interface Log {
    bool save(string msg) {
        if (processMedia(msg)) {
            print "logou!";
            return true;
        } else {
            print "o log falhou!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    virtual bool processMedia(string msg);
}

class LogFile extends Log {
    override bool processMedia(string msg) { 
        try {
            //salva em arquivo aqui
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

classe LogMail extends Log {
    override bool processMedia(string msg) {
        try {
            //envia por e-mail aqui
            return true;
        } catch (SMTPException ex) {
            return false;
        }
}

bool logou = new LogFile().save("deu um erro X aqui neste trecho");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Override.cs).

Isso vai gravar a mensagem de erro em arquivo. Note que chamou o método que só existe no tipo abstrato. Não tem problema porque ele existe no tipo concreto que é derivado de `Log`. E dentro deste método haverá uma chamada ao `processMedia()` que só existe de fato na classe derivada. Aí ocorreu um polimorfismo.

Lembrando que em interface sempre ocorre o polimorfismo (pelo menos nas maioria das linguagens com este mecanismo). Qualquer operação que espere uma interface não poderá executar nada da própria interface, afinal ela não possui implementação. Sempre deverá chamar o método do contrato implementado no tipo concreto.

Comment: No teu exemplo 1 por qual motivo o metodo2() da classe B não tem o `@override` sendo que ele tem a mesma assinatura da classe A ?

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Porque a intenção é **esconder** o método da classe pai em vez de sobrescrevê-lo no senso do polimorfismo. Este exemplo não considera o comportamento Java. Se considerasse, a segunda saída indicada estaria errada já que em Java os métodos são virtuais por padrão e a sobrescrita sempre vai ocorrer. Este exemplo provavelmente considera o comportamento do C#, onde, por outro lado, se você não está sobrescrevendo um método virtual (o que é indicado pela palavra-chave *override*) mas ao invés o está escondendo, é recomendado explicitar sua intenção usando a palavra chave *new*.

Comment: @DavidSchrammel editei para ficar mais claro que a linguagem é fictícia e não Java. Nem C#. Eu tinha usado um exemplo "abstrato" na outra pergunta e segui ele nesta já que ela é um complemento da outro. O exemplo 2 é quase Java, mas também não é :)

Comment: Apenas complementando que além do exemplo não ser em Java, ele não se aplica ao Java pois, ao contrário do exemplo, em Java não é possível esconder (ou "reintroduzir", como é chamado em outras linguagens) um método de instância da classe pai. O primeiro exemplo portanto considera detalhes específicos de alguma linguagem (ele serviria em C# e Delphi, por exemplo) e não a orientação a objetos de maneira geral (ele não serve em Java e Ruby, por exemplo, pois nestas linguagens o método quando redeclarado na classe filha será sempre *override*).