# Como utilizar o foreach para imprimir as informações de um array de objeto? (Java)

Tags: java

Boa noite!

Tenho esta estrutura abaixo e gostaria de saber como poderia utilizar um for each para imprimir as informações deste meu vetor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    Funcionario funcionarios[] = new Funcionario[5];

    String nome;
    double salario;

    for (byte i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("informe o nome: ");
        nome = teclado.nextLine();

        System.out.println("informe o salario");
        salario = Double.parseDouble(teclado.nextLine());

        Funcionario f;
        f = new Funcionario();
        f.nome = nome;
        f.salario = salario;

        funcionarios[i] = f;
    }

    //Este código abaixo foi uma tentativa, não entendi como ele funciona
    for(Funcionario f1 : funcionarios){
        System.out.println(f1);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Oi Lucas, o seu loop está certinho. Qual é a dúvida? Você quer saber como esse loop está funcionando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente, quando você executa esse código, a saída é algo como isto:

`Funcionario@28d93b30`

Isso não tem relação com o *loop*, e, ocorre porque você está imprimindo um objeto, não tipos primitivos como um `int`, `float`, etc. Quando você chama `System.out.println(f1);` ele irá buscar pelo método `toString` da classe funcionário. Daí você pensa: "Eu não tenho nenhum método 'to string' nessa classe".

Em Java, toda classe é subclasse de [**`Object`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) implicitamente, imagine que há um `extends Object` mesmo contra a sua vontade (:P). E se você olhar o [código de implementação](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l235), verá que *object* possui alguns métodos e o `toString` é um deles, ou seja, sempre que você cria uma classe, esse método estará presente.

Se você não [sobrescrever o método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/4808), o código da superclasse será chamado. E a implementação dele é a seguinte:

```
public String toString() {
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Trata-se do nome da classe seguido do `@` e o código hexadecimal do [hashcode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/4808) do objeto.

Então, respondendo, você pode acessar os atributos desse objeto:

```
for(Funcionario f1 : funcionarios){
   System.out.println("Nome: " + f1.nome + ", Salário: " + f1.salario);
}
```

Ou fazer o que (na minha opinião) é muito mais simples: sobrescrever o método `toString`:

```
public class Funcionario {

    public String nome;
    public double salario;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Nome: " + nome + ", Salário: " + salario;
    }
}
```

Desse modo, ao chamar `System.out.println(f1)` o código que foi definido na classe funcionário será executado e você terá uma saída "mais legível" para humanos.

Comment: Boa noite! Sim, eu diminui na verdade a quantidade no for de 5 para 2 somente para testes. obrigado.

Comment: Renan, muito obrigado pela explicação acima! Consegui entender bem como funciona. Grande Abraço.