# Quais são as diferenças entre overrideing e overloading no Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo, sobrecarga, sobrescrita

Quais são as principais diferenças entre *overrideing* e *overloading* no Java? Qual relação existe entre esses termos com o Polimorfismo?

Comment: Relacionada:[Qual a finalidade da @Override?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/28595)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### *Override(ing)*

é sobrescrever, ou seja, definir um novo **comportamento para um método** que já existe. Isso acontece quando a classe em questão herda (estende - *extends*) outra classe qualquer e cria-se um método com a mesma assinatura da classe "pai" na classe filha.

Um exemplo simples

```
public class Animal {
    public void mover() {
        System.out.println("Um animal pode se mover");
    }
}
```

```
public class Cachorro extends Animal {
    public void mover() {
        System.out.println("Cachorro pode caminhar e correr");
    }
}
```

---

### *Overload(ing)*

é o ato de criar vários métodos diferentes com o mesmo o nome, porém com assinaturas diferentes, cada um com sua própria implementação. Especificamente no Java, também é muito usado como uma forma de resolver o "problema" da falta de parâmetros *default*.

Como por exemplo (bem trivial, diga-se de passagem) um método `enviarEmail` com a implementação da rotina e outro método apenas para suprir a falta de parâmetros com valores *default*.

```
public static void enviarEmail(String destinatario) {
    enviarEmail(destinatario, null);
}

public static void enviarEmail(String destinatario, Arquivos[] anexos) {
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    
    if(anexos != null)
        message.addAttachments(anexos);

    message.Send();
}
```

Dessa forma, o consumidor deste serviço não precisa se preocupar em passar parâmetros que não forem usados.

Se a linguagem tivesse este recurso, a implementação método poderia ser algo como

```
public static void enviarEmail(String destinatario, Arquivos[] anexos = null) {
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    
    if(anexos == null)
        message.addAttachments(anexos);

    message.Send();
}
```

---

#### Ok, mas e o polimorfismo?

Partindo do princípio, polimorfismo é uma palavra que vem da junção de duas palavras do grego, *poly* (muitas) e *morph* (formas). Então, segundo esta definição é possível entender que polimorfismo (neste nosso contexto) é a capacidade de uma chamada para um método ter um comportamento diferente dada uma condição específica.

**E como isso acontece?**

No caso do *overriding* de um método isso se dá pelo fato de que cada tipo específico (aqueles que estendem uma classe) pode ter sua própria implementação de determinados métodos. Logo, a mesma chamada de um método vai acabar chamando a implementação dentro da classe referente a sua instância, fazendo assim com que seja possível ter diferentes comportamentos (várias formas) na mesma chamada.

Um exemplo simples, tomando como base o exemplo no início desta resposta

```
public static void moverAnimal(Animal animal) {
    animal.mover();
}
```

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
moverAnimal(animal); // Neste caso, a saída vai ser > Um animal pode se mover

Animal cachorro = new Cachorro();
moverAnimal(cachorro); // Já aqui, a saída será > Cachorro pode caminhar e correr
```

Simples, não? O método `mover` pode ter vários comportamentos (várias formas) diferentes.

No caso do *overloading* de métodos é mais simples ainda, a condição para isso acontecer é a existência (ou ausência) de um parâmetro.

Como no exemplo acima sobre *overloading* eu foquei na simulação de parâmetros *default*, vou criar outro exemplo (bem simplista também) aqui pra ficar mais claro.

```
public void trocarMusica() {
    Musica proxima = encontraProximaMusica();

    if(proxima != null)
        proxima.tocar();
}

public void trocarMusica(Musica proxima) {
    proxima.tocar();
}
```

Perceba que o método que não recebe parâmetro nenhum, apenas obtém a próxima música da lista e, se existir uma próxima, começa a tocá-la. Já o outro método, recebe uma música específica por parâmetro e começa a tocá-la.

Os *generics* do Java também são uma forma de polimorfismo.

Comment: Li sim tudinho, pode ficar despreocupado! Muito bom. Vlw

Comment: Exemplo bacana ficou bem mais claro.