# Existe diferença em como o polimorfismo no Java e no C# é aplicado?

Tags: java, c#, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando os conceitos de POO e me gerou uma dúvida.

No Java acredito que consigo acessar todos os métodos e atributos declarados como public em uma subclasse mesmo quando utilizo uma variável do tipo da superclasse para referenciar essa subclasse.

Porém, em C# não consigo acessar os métodos da subclasse quando faço a atribuição de sua referência para uma super classe?

Existe essa diferença entre as linguagens? Se sim, por que, se o conceito de POO teoricamente é o mesmo para qualquer linguagem de programação?

Exemplo:

```
ContaPoupanca poupanca = new ContaPoupanca();
poupanca.CalculaInvestimento();

Conta conta = new ContaPoupanca();
conta.CalculaInvestimento();  // Não consigo acessar esse método através da variável conta.
```

Comment: Se o método é exclusivo do subtipo, [**não vai funcionar nem no java**](https://ideone.com/ZrX6XR).

Comment: Isso num tem a ver com o fato de que todo método não privado do Java é equivalente ao método virtual do C#?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ?!?!?!!?! :)

Comment: @bigown, posso estar me confundindo... mas vamos lá; na seção [10.5.3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx) a documentação fala de **The implementation of a non-virtual method is invariant** (tipo, não olha `vtable`), enquanto que **In contrast, the implementation of a virtual method can be superseded by derived classes.** (tipo, olha `vtable`); no Java, todo método não privado sofre esse _superseded_ mencionado, inclusive o bytecode para chamar método de instância não privado tem como mnemônico `invokeVirtual`, dizendo que sempre vai verificar a `vtable`.

Comment: Não isto não ocorre de fato porque se é privado não tem porque olhar em outro lugar. Mas acho que agora entendi o que quiser dizer. No Java todo método público é virtual por *default*, e o no C# é não virtual por *default*. Aí sim. Mas em essência não muda o comportamento, só o *default* é outro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No java acredito que consigo acessar todos os métodos e atributos declarados como public em uma subclasse mesmo quando utilizo uma variável do tipo da superclasse para referenciar essa subclasse.

Não, não pode.

Não faz sentido acessar membros de um subtipo num tipo superior. Em nenhuma das duas linguagens isso vai funcionar.

Isso, na verdade, não tem nada a ver com polimorfismo. Seria interessante dar uma lida na publicação abaixo

- [Quais são as diferenças entre overriding e overloading no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189895/18246)

Comment: Jurava que eu tinha acessado o método da subclasse usando um tipo da super classe. Vou fazer o teste novamente.

Answer (score 7):

A resposta do LINQ já disse que não dá, mas tem solução. Vou chutar mais ou menos como seria a classe que precisa:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        ContaPoupanca poupanca = new ContaPoupanca();
        poupanca.CalculaInvestimento();
        Conta conta = new ContaPoupanca();
        conta.CalculaInvestimento();
    }
}

public class Conta {
    public virtual void CalculaInvestimento() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
public class ContaPoupanca : Conta {
    public override void CalculaInvestimento() { WriteLine("ok"); }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DyVpqq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0I9LNV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/tree/master/CSharp/Method).

Se é o que precisa é outra estória.

Comment: Isso seria o equivalente ao método abstract no java ou nada a ver?

Comment: Não, se o método fosse abstrato a classe também deveria ser, aí ela não poderia ser instanciada. Na verdade vou até melhorar o código, assim que minha internet que está horrível deixar.