# Qual a relação entre encapsulamento e polimorfismo?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo, encapsulamento

A alguns dias atrás, eu estava conversando com um amigo sobre Java, e perguntei que parte da matéria eles estavam estudando. Então ele respondeu que estavam iniciando os estudos sobre herança.

Como eles estavam muito atrasados, eu perguntei como eles deram um salto para herança repentinamente, perguntei se já haviam estudado sobre polimorfismo e encapsulamento, então ele respondeu:

> Não é tudo a mesma coisa?

No momento eu não pensei em nada, afinal eu estou aprendendo e ele já tem até faculdade. Mas analisando melhor e partindo do princípio de que duas coisas não(devem) ser a mesma, até pelos nomes diferentes,

- Polimorfismo e encapsulamento são a mesma coisa?
- Existem relações entre eles esses dois conceitos, a ponto de falar "que são a mesma coisa"?
- Se não forem a mesma coisa, poderiam dar algumas explicações e se possível, um exemplo de como funcionam?

Comment: Relacionada (?): [Quais são as diferenças entre overriding e overloading no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189895/18246)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não é tudo a mesma coisa.

Faculdade quer dizer muito pouco. Ela é útil, mas ter um diploma não garante nada. A maioria dos estudantes aprendem ser ótimos jogadores de truco no pátio da escola. Em geral as pessoas procuram aprender fragmentos e acham que sabem tudo. Poucos são comprometidos com o entendimento correto. Menos ainda são os que possuem criticidade para evitar sair falando sobre o que não sabe. E quando a pessoa aprende, em geral é *decoreba* e nem entende sobre o que está falando.

Em geral OOP é como sexo de adolescente, todo mundo diz que faz, mas fazer mesmo, poucos. E onde faz, não sei se deveria. OOP de verdade complica muito o código, então talvez seja melhor não fazer OOP certo mesmo, o problema é que precisa não fazer com consciência e não por acaso.

A maioria [sequer consegue definir o que é OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) e cada mecanismo comumente usado nesse paradigma. Sem falar que há escolas diferentes que definem o termo.

Esses dois mecanismos, junto com a herança são a base da orientação a objeto, embora alguns discordem. Eles têm nomes diferentes porque são muito diferentes.

Algumas definições colocam a abstração como outro componente.

Inclusive eles podem e são usados em outros paradigmas de forma conjunta ou separada. Não é algo exclusivo de OOP.

Não há qualquer relação entre eles, são completamente [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101).

## Encapsulamento

[Encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101) até poderia ser confundido com abstração, mesmo sendo diferente. Ele é sobre esconder os detalhes de implementação.

Ao contrário do que muitos acham, *getters* e *setters* servem ao encapsulamento, mas ele não é encapsulamento em si, isso é abstração. Encapsulamento é sobre manter junto o necessário para alcançar o objetivo do objeto, então tudo o que pode ser feito com aquele objeto deve fazer parte dele, mas não deve ser exposto diretamente, a não ser que seja necessário. Na verdade isso é até um pouco mais complicado, porque é comum que queiramos que a maioria das operações com um objeto sejam feitas fora dele, mas isso é outro assunto.

Tornar algo privado é um mecanismo muito usado, mas estritamente falando não é o encapsulamento em si.

Encapsular não é separar o programa em partes.

Tragicamente os *getters* e *setters* são exemplificados como encapsulamento e como as pessoas não entendem bem o conceito acham que é só isto. Curiosamente os que gostam de boas práticas deveriam conhecer a boa prática que diz que eles não são bons, eles apenas costumam ser melhores do que deixar tudo público quando não tem outro jeito, [a não ser quando eles não são](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101).

## Polimorfismo

[Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) é sobre escolher o melhor algoritmo para uma determinada necessidade.

Existem algumas formas de polimorfismo, mas todas, de um jeito ou de outro, [são substitutos para um `if`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/101). O polimorfismo mais tradicional, o dinâmico ou de subtipo é apenas a escolha de qual método executar baseado no tipo do objeto que possui alguma relação, em geral é feita uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) na chamada do método de acordo com uma tabela.

O [polimorfismo paramétrico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) normalmente é resolvido em tempo de compilação de acordo com o tipo do dado usado e alguma restrição.

Ainda é possível ter um polimorfismo dinâmico ou estático, baseado na [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), chamado [*overloading*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101) ou *ad-hoc*, que não é o que tratamos aqui, não é disto que OOP trata.

## Informações extras

Tem um monte de perguntas sobre o assunto aqui mesmo no SOpt, é só pesquisar. Se achar algo que não foi perguntado, pode fazer uma nova pergunta.

## Exemplo

Pode ter erros, não sei nem se compila, é só para mostrar os conceitos, fiz enormes simplificações. Note que não tem uma relação tão direta entre os métodos e os campos. Não caí na [ilusão de encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101). Java incentiva o polimorfismo fazendo todos os métodos serem virtuais por padrão. Veja:

```
public abstract class Conta {
    private string documento; //todos aqui estão encapsulados
    private string titular;
    private BigDecimal saldo;
    private BigDecimal limite;
    private Date ultimaTroca;
    public Conta(string documento, string nome, BigDecimal saldo, BigDecimal limite) {
        if (!validaDocumento(documento)) throw DocumentoInvalaidoException();
        this.documento = documento
        this.nome = nome;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.limite = limite;
        ultimaTroca = new Date();
    }
    private bool trocaEstaDisponivel() { //encapsula a lógica de verificação, não interessa externamente
        return new Date().getTime() - ultimaTroca.getTime() < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 6;
    }
    private bool PodeSacar(BigDecimal saque) {
        return saldo + limite - saque >= 0;
    }
    protected abstract bool ValidaDocumento(string documento);  //encapsulado só entre a hierarquia, haverá polimorfismo
    public abstract bool CadastroValido(); //é polimorfico, só o descendente terá implementação
    public bool TrocaNome(string nome) { //público é o que pode fazer publicamente, o resto é detalhe interno
        if (trocaEstaDisponivel()) {
            this.nome = nome;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void Deposita(BigDecimal deposito) {
        saldo += deposito;
    }
    public bool Saca(BigDecimal saque) {
        if (PodeSacar(saque)) {
            saldo -= saque;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class ContaJuridica : Conta {
    public ContaJuridica(string documento, string nome, BigDecimal saldo, BigDecimal limite) {
        Conta(documento, nome, saldo, limite);
    }
    @Override protected ValidaDocumento(string documento) {
        return true; //só para facilitar, aqui verificaria o CNPJ
    }
    @Override public CadastroValido() {
        return true; //aqui iria buscar na receita se o cadastro está ativou ou fazer outra coisa
    }
}
    
//o mesmo poderia ser feito para pessoa fisica

public class main() {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ContaJuridica conta = new ContaJuridica("01456789000159", "João da Silva", 100, 50);
        conta.Deposita(20);
        if (!conta.trocaNome("José da Silva)) System.out.println("Não pode ficar trocando nome toda hora");
        if (!conta.Saca(200)) System.out.println("Tá achando que o saco não tem fundo?");
        testarConta(conta.CadastroValido());
    }
    public void TestaConta(Conta conta) { //note que recebe uma Conta e não ContaJuridica, então o uso será polimorfico
        if (!conta.CadastroValido()) System.out.println("Sua conta precisa ser regularizada"); //chama método de ContaJuridica
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/EncapsulationExample.java).

Comment: Cadê o resto da resposta?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado calma, a gente chega lá :)

Answer (score 1):

Encapsular é separar o programa em partes, deixando ele o mais separado possível. Isso com o intuito de proteger os dados manipulados dentro da classe.

Polimorfismo é uma especialização. Escolher o melhor algoritmo para uma determinada classe.
Um exemplo de polimorfismo é a função "mover". Para jogos de xadrez e dama, ela terá um comportamento diferente.