# Se eu posso fazer tudo com programação estrutural, por que criaram a orientada a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Na pergunta sobre - [Tudo que consigo fazer em POO eu consigo fazer em PE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211768/tudo-que-consigo-fazer-em-poo-eu-consigo-fazer-em-pe) - a resposta aceita e mais bem votada diz que:

> Sim, qualquer linguagem de programação pode fazer tudo. Agora, cada paradigma tem seu jeito de organizar, então nem sempre pode-se fazer do mesmo jeito. Mais ainda, com algumas linguagens e uso de determinados paradigmas é possível que tarefas específicas sejam mais fáceis de fazer em um paradigma do que em outro.

Ou seja, afirma que é possível, e que qualquer linguagem de programação pode fazer tudo, seja estrutural ou orientada à objetos.

Pensando nisso, gostaria de saber: se "qualquer linguagem de programação pode fazer tudo",

- Por que criaram a orientação a objetos?
- Foi uma necessidade de incrementar a linguagem / melhorá-la? Ou foi simplesmente para seguir a "modinha"?

<sup>P.S.: Visões mais gerais das linguagens, ao meu ponto de vista podem ser respondidas, mas gostaria de saber em específico a linguagem PHP.</sup>

Comment: "*é possível que tarefas específicas sejam mais fáceis de fazer em um paradigma do que em outro*" já não responde essa pergunta?

Comment: Long story short: OO foca muito o encapsulamento, podendo ser usado até em C; suporte a OO na linguagem permite usar as coisas boas de OO numa sintaxe mais enxuta

Comment: Pelo mesmo motivo que com cavalos se ia a qualquer lugar, mas mesmo assim houve quem quisesse inventar carros e trens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para organizar melhor códigos **complexos**, para tratar melhor domínios extensos. Sim, fazer OOP em *scripts*, aplicações fugazes, simples, não é vantajoso. Mas por sorte muitas pessoas não fazem OOP nessas coisas, ainda que dizem que fazem.

OOP é modinha se considerar que as pessoas usam onde não deve. Modinha não é algo passageiro, é algo que só está sendo usado porque as pessoas usam, sem um motivo claro. Não é modinha quando usado onde é útil. É muito modinha quando a pessoa fala que está fazendo e nem está, [ela só quer fazer parte do grupo que está "bombando"](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/comments/6imnzj/%C3%A9_rid%C3%ADculo_como_as_modas_digitais_se_tornam_um/?st=j49y1jvm&sh=275cad8b). E como eu disse em [resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214772/101), é sexo de adolescente.

A criação de OOP não tem nada de modinha. A maioria das tecnologias não são modinhas. O mesmo não se pode dizer de várias metodologias que até foram criadas para atender uma necessidade, mas [não cumprem o prometido](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/comments/6ivydf/notdd_eric_gunnersons_compendium/?st=j49y5qpf&sh=e84e5412).

É como porte de arma, só para pegar um exemplo. Ele é útil, mas defender que todo mundo deve poder ter uma arma é modinha. Não atende uma necessidade real, mas sim uma inventada.

Em PHP de forma geral é modinha. Tem caso que não é, mas é raro. E sinceramente quando é adequado, normalmente é a linguagem errada para aquele problema. PHP é umas linguagens mais de *script* que existe, até a forma de nomear variável indica isso. Colocar OOP em PHP foi e ainda é modinha. Claro que a definição mais precisa disto é **sobrevivência**. Hoje poucas coisas precisam de *scripts* (ou até tem várias, mas que você cria em um estalar de dedos e encerra, não gera trabalho), o grosso do desenvolvimento são em cima de coisas complexas. Sem OOP a linguagem definharia a um nicho muito pequeno, o que aconteceu com Perl. Mas aí a linguagem ficou inconsistente.

OOP é muito mais difícil de entender e fazer certo, tanto que quase todo mundo faz errado. É muito comum as pessoas complicarem seu *design* para tentar ser OOP sem trazer vantagem alguma.

OOP é ótima nesses casos de muitas relações entre objetos, quando os objetos são muito complexos, quando há relações de subtipo, hierarquias. GUI se beneficia muito disso. Jogos costumam se beneficiar, alguns tipos de negócios, mas bem mais raros. *Frameworks* e bibliotecas mais complexas podem ser beneficiar muito.

Reforço que a resposta fala que OOP e PE são coisas muito distintas. Gostaria que todo mundo lesse os *links* lá para entender um pouco mais sobre OOP (eu sei que não respondi totalmente) e entender que programação estruturada é algo muito simples e foca em outro aspecto da programação que OOP não foca. Programação estruturada não é sobre organização de código, é sobre o fluxo do algoritmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Cada tipo de paradigma de programação serve um propósito, mas como dissestes, estrutural pode fazer as funções de uma Orientada a Objetos, porém quando se trata única e exclusivamente de Objetos, as linguagens de POO são bem mais fáceis de se trabalhar e gerenciam (na maioria) a memória de uma melhor maneira para esse propósito.

POO tem conceitos de herança, classes Abstratas(Java) e encapsulamento, o que é o foco desse paradigma, que salva o programador de muitas linhas de código.

Se fossemos seguir a lógica de que uma única linguagem é fundamental estaríamos programando em Assembly até hoje, ou até mesmo em Binário, o que não parece muito convidativo, certo?

Então a resposta do porque outras linguagens são criadas é simples: Cada uma serve um propósito, mas com a evolução natural a linguagem ela vem abrangendo um maior conteúdo.

Vale a leitura de [Paradigmas de programação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigma_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e suas [diferenças](http://tiserviceprovider.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/tipos-de-paradigmas-de-programacao-mais.html)

Comment: A impressão que eu tive que não foi isso que foi perguntado.