# É obrigatório que o código seja POO no desenvolvimento em C#? Ou pode ser estruturado?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação

Creio que estruturado até pode ser e, caso sim, o que perco com isso?
Ademais, ainda na possibilidade de ser possível não usar POO em C#, alguém conhece algum curso que implemente o código sem usar POO?

> O motivo da pergunta:
> Por mais que eu tente, não consigo absorver as
> técnicas e conceitos da POO. Em bom e claro português, não consigo
> aprender!

Comment: Pergunta que vai gerar opiniões, a linguagem é orientada a objeto, mas, nada impede fazer diferente, apesar que esse aspecto de fazer diferente pode trazer só problemas. Se tem dificuldades em aprender essa linguagem tente mudar, quem sabe se de melhor em linguagens com outro paradigma de programação. Na minha opinião (tavendo é opinião) você está na linguagem errada.

Comment: Eu concordo com você: Também acho que estou na linguagem errada. Vou te perguntar uma coisa que talvez não tenha resposta, ou que pelas regras da plataforma você não possa responder porque vai gerar opiniões: Você recomenda alguma (ou algumas) linguagem com outro paradigma de programação?

Comment: Isso `...alguém conhece algum curso que implemente o código sem usar POO?...* foge ao nosso escopo não deveria estar na pergunta. Ref-> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5487#5487

Comment: Leia [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/)

Comment: @AdemirSpitzer Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o tour como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

> É obrigatório que o código seja POO no desenvolvimento em C#?

Não precisa ser, mas há fortes incentivos para isso. Em coisas simples não deve fazer OOP, mas em algo mais complexo fica difícil não usar. E é quase impossível não consumir, que é diferente de fazer OOP em algum nível em C# porque toda biblioteca foi construída assim.

E dá para fazer códigos simples em C#, até mesmo *scripts*.

> Ou pode ser estruturado?

Não só pode como deve. Jamais faça programação não estruturada.

Parece que acha que programação estruturada é antagônica de OOP, mas não é.

- [Quais são as características da programação estruturada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101)
- [O que é programação procedural e não procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101)
- [Tudo que consigo fazer em POO eu consigo fazer em PE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101)
- [Se eu posso fazer tudo com programação estrutural, por que criaram a orientada a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215015/101)

> Creio que estruturado até pode ser e, caso sim, o que perco com isso?

Como pode ver nos *links* não faz muito sentido.

> Por mais que eu tente, não consigo absorver as técnicas e conceitos da POO

Não é um bom motivo para não usar, a falha permanecerá.

Observando as afirmações e a experiência que vejo em quase todos os casos a dificuldade de aprendizado de algo mais avançado é ter falhas no mais básico, então se resolve não aprender o avançado fica sem ele e com o básico falho. Para aprender o avançado precisa consertar tudo o que não aprendeu, ou aprendeu errado do básico, aí resolve a questão.

C# de fato é uma linguagem que dificulta o uso para quem aprendeu mais ou menos. A pessoa até consegue, mas só aproveitará bem dominando a linguagem por completo em todos os paradigmas, inclusive o funcional, e claro, muito bem o imperativo, caso contrário fará várias coisas erradas.

De fato OOP é das coisas mais difíceis de aprender, pelo menos do jeito certo, as pessoas que aprendem com muita facilidade estão perto da genialidade ou aprenderam errado. OOP não é o que as pessoas acham que é, a grande maioria não sabe corretamente e acreditam em mágicas que prometem sobre isso, mas a pessoa só está repetindo o que ouviu dizer, ela não entende aquilo, ela só repete chavões.

Comment: Olá, Maniero! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, links, sugestões, observações e afins. Você está coberto de razões e uma coisa que você disse, ao menos, me conforta numa coisa: OOP não é fácil! Quem aprende rápido é quase gênio ou aprendeu de forma errada. O @novic acertou em cheio: Pensando da forma como estou, significa que estou na linguagem errada.

Answer (score -4):

Você está querendo aprender a programar para qual intuíto? Mais por hobbie ou para trabalhar com isso?
Cara, a POO permite você reaproveitar MUITOS códigos!
Eu ainda sou novato nessa área de programação, comecei no ano passado, estou trabalhando na área vai fazer 1 ano em Outubro e te digo que em empresas de software, sempre vai ter POO. Justamente pela possíbilidade de criar e usar códigos mais "limpos" e poder reaproveitar o mesmo.
Isso poupa muito tempo em manutenção de código, além de deixar o mesmo mais organizado.

Comment: Olá, Matheus! Não é para me engajar financeiramente, mas como sou comerciante, tenho algumas necessidades que hoje são atendidas pelo Excel, então eu colocaria mais como hobbie. Já fui programador numa empresa num SGBD chamado ZIM (década de 90) rodando em terminais Unix, depois em Uniface e, por fim, em ABAP/4, linguagem do ERP R/3 da SAP. Aí as coisas tomaram outros rumos, me aventurei no comércio, e há 13 anos estou afastado da programação. Foi só um pouco de história para explicar o que pretendo, mas concordo contigo e com o @Maniero: Se for aprender, aprenda corretamente!

Comment: Entendi!
Realmente, eu concordo com o @Maniero, aprende da maneira certa, além de deixar o projeto que você pretende fazer mais fácil para dar manutenção!

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).

Answer (score -4):

C# é uma linguagem que podes ser imperativa, declarativa, funcional, ou orientada a objetos. No geral se aprende C# orientado a objetos pois é a forma mais famosa atualmente.

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).