# Exemplo real do uso de encapsulamento

Tags: engenharia-de-software, encapsulamento

Pesquisei sobre encapsulamento, inclusive li alguns tópicos por aqui, mas ainda não vi um exemplo real do uso disso de forma que consiga me mostrar suas vantagens, quais problemas ele evita.

Tenho um atributo do tipo `public`, mas é um costume dos programadores fazê-lo `private` e criar suas propriedades `get` e `set`. Pois bem, mas nunca mostram um exemplo real, de um sistema que já fizeram, das vantagens de se utilizar isso e dos problemas que ocorreram e foram solucionados.

Vi exemplificações em vídeos do YouTube, mas não vejo o porquê de terem alterado do `public` para o `private`, não demonstram quais problemas evitariam. Já li alguns artigos, vi alguns vídeos, mas eu só queria um exemplo real e objetivo mostrando as variáveis para o `private` porque evita esse tipo de problema e as vantagens são exatamente essas.

Comment: Chegou a ver: [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/91)

Comment: Pior que eu já vi, não ficou claro para mim essa questão, mas vou ver de novo...

Comment: Nesses casos sempre lembro do clássico exemplo da conta do banco. Se você deixar tudo público e acessível de qualquer parte do código, campos importantes como saldo poderão ser acessados de maneira indesejada por qualquer um, sem o cuidado necessário à segurança. Por isso é necessário que tais campos sejam private e possam ser acessados apenas pelos geters e setters.

Comment: @Max sinto te dizer que este é o motivo errado para encapsular, o exemplo é ruim (eu sei que todo mundo usa ele, por isso que OOP é tão mal usado por aí), e *getter/setter*  não resolve o problema. Eu vou responder.

Comment: @HeyJoe A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 6):

Não é obrigação de um objeto ter *getter* e *setter* para cada <strike>atributo</strike> campo (porém expô-los diretamente como públicos costuma ser pior ainda). Tem que criar esses métodos somente quando é necessário expor diretamente a informação (o que geralmente não deveria ser a intenção) e nem precisa ser o par, pode ser por exemplo só um deles.

Campos internos do objeto são detalhes de implementação, juntamente com os algoritmos internos que os manipulam. No espírito da orientação a objetos está um princípio mais geral que é deixar a implementação escondida e expor somente uma interface de programação (um conjunto de métodos acessíveis externamente - leia-se não-privados, no caso do Java) estável que permite manipular e fazer uso desse estado interno, e que não necessariamente possui uma relação de um para um com os campos do objeto.

Um *getter* ou *setter* pode ser meio caminho andado nesse sentido, se houver a necessidade de realmente expor esse tipo de interface. O artigo [*Encapsulation is not information hiding*](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075271/core-java/encapsulation-is-not-information-hiding.html), que pode lhe interessar, cita o exemplo de um objeto representando uma coordenada geográfica: latitude e longitude só admitem certos intervalos de valores, e o encapsulamento ajuda a setá-los dentro de limites válidos. Esse é um exemplo de *setters* que fazem validação dos valores recebidos.

Não uso tanto *setters*, mas faço bastante validação em construtores. Se um <strike>parâmetro</strike> argumento foi passado incorretamente eu já disparo por exemplo uma `IllegalArgumentException`: *"você está tentando construir errado o objeto!"* Também é uma forma de encapsulamento.

Em projetos reais também já usei um *getter* que precisava retornar uma cópia de uma coleção (sabe o que é, né? Uma classe que armazena elementos, como uma lista, um conjunto, etc). Dentro do objeto havia uma coleção de elementos imutáveis. Eu queria retornar um subconjunto dessa coleção ou então uma cópia dela, para que se o código-cliente tentasse modificar a coleção retornada, não modificasse minha coleção original. Modificar os elementos já estava garantido que não seria possível, pois estes eram imutáveis. Fiz então um *getter* que retornava uma cópia ou subconjunto da coleção. Pronto.

Outro exemplo: um *getter* que retornava o status conectado (verdadeiro ou falso) de uma central de alarme. Essa central encapsulava um `Socket` do Java e a informação de conectado vinha de `socket.isClosed()`. Observe que não é um simples `getCampo()` ou `isCampo()`. Ele faz um processamento, embora mínimo, que é inverter o valor retornado (`isClosed()` retorna se está fechado, eu tinha um `isConectada()` que retorna se a conexão está aberta).

Comment: Já leio com calma mas gostei da notação do riscado pra indicar que se usa o termo errado :)

Comment: @Maniero Acredite, é mais lembrete para mim do que para os outros :P apesar de que de tanto errar a gente vai aprendendo :)

Answer (score 6):

Você tem razão, a maioria das pessoas seguem estas "recomendações" porque viram em algum lugar e elas que estão "ensinando" outras pessoas também não sabem porque fazem isto. Algumas acham que sabem.

De fato, as respostas dadas no [*link* acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101) do rray mostra bem que *getter* e *setter* por si só não podem ser considerados encapsulamento. Só porque deixou um [campo (e não atributo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) privado não quer dizer que está encapsulando algo, principalmente quando coloca um *getter* e *setter* direto para ele sem pensar no que está fazendo.

Cada vez mais estou convencido que *getter*/*setter* e outros métodos que servem de anteparo para acessar o real estado é abstração e não encapsulamento. Ok, sei que não será bem aceito porque a definição que é usual no nosso meio diz que esse mecanismo é o encapsulamento. Então não espero que as pessoas mudem sua visão e não vou insistir nisso. Me parece que encapsulamento é deixar tudo o que é necessário ao objeto no próprio objeto. Se alguém perguntar mais sobre, eu posso dar uma resposta.

De que adianta ter um campo privado e um par de métodos que acessa normalmente o campo da mesma forma que ele seria acessado direto? Como isso pode ser encapsulamento? Acho que pode ser abstração, porque a abstração pressupõe que o mecanismo interno concreto não importa.

Encapsulamento tem a ver com o fato de que o comportamento para mudar o estado do objeto está junto do próprio objeto. Então haverá um método que fará a mudança ou acesso ao valor do campo. Mas nada diz que deve ser *getter* ou *setter*. E pra mim isso viola a abstração maior do objeto porque é apenas um anteparo para o detalhe de implementação, ajuda, mas não resolve por completo o problema de mater o conceito do objeto genérico, você não está expondo o detalhe de implementação, mas está expondo como é esse detalhe, o que dá quase na mesma.

Mas pode ser também. Se o único comportamento para acessar/mudar o campo é diretamente relacionado ao estado de forma pura e simples, tudo bem. O importante para o encapsulamento é que o comportamento que permita o acesso/mutação do campo esteja no mesmo objeto.

Há uma corrente que prega que nunca deveria ter métodos *setters* e talvez nem *getters*. Essas pessoas dizem, e até dou razão, que deveria ter métodos que mandam fazer certas ações que vão manipular o estado de alguma forma, mas que não seja algo tão direto.

Discordo um pouco porque há muitos casos que a única coisa que você deve fazer com o campo é mudar seu valor, e em grande parte das vezes para pegar algum dado é só pegar o valor do campo.

Claro, o pessoal abusa, até por não entender como aplicar essa técnica corretamente. Quando uma classe está cheia de *getters* e principalmente *setters* realmente deve ter algo errado. Aí prefiro um modelo anêmico simples.

Para exemplificar usando o motivador do max nos comentários acima: você não deve ter um `getSaldo()` e `setSaldo()`, deve ter um `Depositar()` e `Sacar()`, entre outros métodos que podem mudar o saldo. Talvez um `getSaldo()` faça sentido, mas uma simples mudança de nome de método pode dar uma outra impressão, algo como `ObtemSaldo()` ou `PedeSaldo()`. Precisa entender o que é operação para dar bons nomes, uma das coisas que eu gosto em DDD :).

Note que o método `Sacar()` faz muito mais que apenas mexer no saldo, ele não é um simples *setter*, além da obviedade que ele não muda o saldo de forma direta, ele fará uma subtração.

Eu fiz um exemplo em [Qual a relação entre encapsulamento e polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214767/101). Acho que ele serve como o exemplo pedido.

Se você usa um construtor adequadamente então tem uma necessidade bem baixa de usar *setters*. A validação ali pode ser considerada como um encapsulamento conforme disse o Piovezan em sua resposta, afinal ela está junto do seu objeto.

Pra mim o maior erro do uso desses mecanismos é ser só um anteparo para o campo como é quase todos *getters* e *setters* que eu vejo sendo usados.

Muitas vezes o adequado para pegar informação é pegar um conjunto e não apenas um campo só, aí também entraria a mesma ideia que o método não deve só retornar o estado de um campo. Claro, para fazer isso provavelmente criará uma complicação porque talvez tenha que criar uma classe só para suportar o conjunto de campos que retornará em determinada situação.

Ainda seguindo a resposta do Piovezan, mesmo que ele tenha usado o termo `getXXX()` em algum método, não sei se todos podem ser considerados como *getters*. Se ele retorna um subconjunto de uma coleção de dados, será que isso por si só já não é um método com um significado especial? Chamar algo de *getter* significa que ele não tem função alguma além de dar um valor, não tem semântica específica, ele passa ser parte do mecanismo do objeto e não do seu significado.

Note que algumas linguagens oferecem melhores mecanismos para trabalhar com essas coisas, como propriedades e tuplas.

Eu sei que isso é algo complicado de explicar, abstrações são pouco entendidas pelos humanos. Imagine criar abstrações certas, por isso falo que OOP é muito difícil. Preciso achar um jeito de melhor explicar sobre mecanismo e semântica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vou defender meu _getter_. O princípio do encapsulamento dita que implementação é separada da interface fornecida pelo objeto. Então embora o _getter_ deva retornar uma informação do objeto, não há obrigação dele retornar um campo. Essa informação poderia ser gerada em tempo real, por exemplo. No caso ela está sendo gerada a partir dos valores de um campo, e embora não seja o caso de se chamar `getCampo()`, ela é ainda um `getAlgumaCoisa()` (como no caso eram `getSetoresInibidos()`). Em todo caso, vou retirar da resposta, ou trocar por outro exemplo.

Comment: Você tem razão nisso, talvez eu não tenha sido tão claro, é que não é o típico *getter*. Eu acho que ele é mais que um *getter*, além de ser um *getter*, ele tem significado, ele funciona como algo mais útil para o objeto do que um *getter*. Eu não disse que é um erro seu e não acho que deva retirar, note que eu faço perguntas e não afirmações. Eu vou tentar melhorar, mas antes preciso pesquisar um pouco, porque é dessas respostas que vai me fazer pensar bastante e concluir coisas interessantes.

Comment: Apenas uma idéia que pode ajudar o pessoal mais leigo (como eu) a entender: uma aplicação de objeto que não tenha "getter e setter típicos" em algo mais comum, como sistema de usuários, produtos, funcionários etc. Na minha opinião, os getter e setter simples são muito usados porque a maioria dos sistemas são relativamente simples

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam você tem razão, eu só não entendo porque alguém usa OOP em sistema simples. OOP é pra gerenciar complexidade.

Comment: Pessoalmente eu não uso OOP nem em sistema complexo (exceto aplicação android nativa), em PHP uso mais funções separadas apenas por arquivos (organização) e array para guardar dados, em JS quando preciso de um objeto, para enviar para o banco por exemplo, crio um anônimo com `{var1: 'var 1', ...}`