# Estou fazendo polimorfismo da forma correta?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Tenho uma classe principal de vendas, e outras subclasses que utilizariam como herança a classe de venda.

Pensei em utilizar o polimorfismo, para além de utilizar como herança métodos em comum, pensei em injetar comportamentos individuais de cada subclasse chamando mesmo assim o método parente.

Exemplo:

```
class vendas {
    public function save(x) {
        return x+x;
    }
}

class pdv extends vendas {
    public function save(x) {
        //Comportamento injetado devido a particularidade da classe pdv
        $this->validarXPdv(x)
        
        //Utilização do metodo herdado
        return parent::save(x);
    }

     public function validarXPdv(x) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Isso seria uma prática ruim? Teria alguma alternativa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto está conceitualmente errado, e usando o termo que usou na pergunta, é uma prática ruim (ainda que eu não goste dele porque isso faz a pessoa achar que é regra mágica). Pelo menos é o que posso dizer avaliando o que está na pergunta, que me obriga inferir certas coisas. Ou seja, sem informação adequada não dá para responder bem isso.

As pessoas acham que orientação a objeto é usar os [mecanismos básicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101) dela como herança, polimorfismo e [encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293801/101) (que [as pessoas nem entendem o que é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/101) e fazem outra coisa), mas na verdade é fazer o objeto ter um significado e se esses mecanismos serviram para isso, ótimo. Então só saber se tem um método em comum não basta para definir se a herança é adequada. Eu posso ter um `save()` em `Pdv` tanto quanto em `Relatorio`, ou `Texto`, ou `Banco`, ou `Abobrinha` que nada têm a ver com `Pdv`.

Ao contrário do que as pessoas acham, herança não serve para pegar métodos quaisquer de outras classes, serve para mostrar que há uma relação clara entre essas definições de tipos. A herança é só um caminho para fazer isso. Não é para pegar qualquer coisa sem sentido e herdar.

Com exemplos artificiais tipo `Vendas` que tem um `save()` que não faz algo útil, ou algo que funciona biologicamente e é uma herança clara, mas que não se encontra na prática em sistema algum (a não ser de biologia) as pessoas não podem aprender o que de fato precisam fazer em um sistema real.

Isso é bem definido por [Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). A herança só se dá quando um objeto tem uma classificação clara acima dele que define integralmente o que ele é. Diz-se que o objeto **é um** outro objeto.

`Pdv` não é um `Vendas`. Um PDV faz vendas, mas não é um, portanto não faz sentido ter herança só pelo nome. E se não for dar nomes adequados para as coisas pra que programar orientado a objeto? Isso é fundamental nesse paradigma.

Mas quero reforçar que nem dá para responder com propriedade porque nem nessa classe `Vendas` e nem no complemento da pergunta diz para que ela serve, e não dá para programar corretamente assim.

Parece que não precisa de herança aí, mas se precisar tem que ser com uma classe que generaliza o que é um `Pdv`, não dizer que ele tem alguma coisa útil para esse PDV.

Piora ainda mais que `Vendas` é `final` e não pode ser herdada, aí está completamente errado.

Herança não foi criada para injetar o que você precisa no objeto.

É possível usar um [*trait*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219197/101) para injetar comportamentos à uma classe. Mas isso precisa ser feito com critério, se for só um mecanismo para usar algo que já existe, está errado, precisa ter semântica, precisa ver onde vai usar isso, porque só será útil se em alguns lugares receber esse *trait* para fazer essa operação específica, e esse comportamento for sempre igual, o que eu duvido que seja nesse caso. Mas novamente, só poderia dizer se eu conhecesse o contexto todo. Quando não se tem todos requisitos corretos o código sairá errado por definição.

Então é preciso um entendimento global do problema específico e de toda a orientação a objeto, não é uma receita de bolo que fará a pessoa acertar. É fácil dizer que esse caso está erado, mas isso não quer dizer que outras situações serão assim, inclusive para tudo tem exceção. Esse é um caso que parece causar um [acoplamento desnecessário e faz o objeto ser menos coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não me atentei ao **Final**, vou estudar sobre oque comentou, a classe  Vendas, seria um crud principal, poderia ter utilizado no exemplo **CrudVendas**, mas minha ideia é que qualquer um que queria utilizar uma função do **CrudVendas**, possa adicionar comportamentos sem reescrever todo código.

Comment: Parece errado. Esse costuma ser um erro clássico de herança, mas sempre depende de muitos detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma prática ruim não, desde que bem estruturada quanto ao contexto e responsabilidade. Isto quer dizer, não adicione métodos na superclasse para forçar um comportamento nas subclasses que não seja natural ao contexto de uso delas.

Uma outra possibilidade, pensando em contexto e que PHP não possui herança múltipla, seria usar Traits para adicionar funcionalidades a classes filha.

Vou usar o bom e velho exemplo de herança com classes de animais.

Imagine uma superclasse animal, que possui o método comer, ok todos animais comem, mas, como eles comem diferentemente uns dos outros em grandes grupos, por exemplo os mamíferos em relação às aves, usaríamos a tua solução chamando o método da superclasse quando sobreposto o método comer nas subclasses, claro, quando necessário reaproveitar o comportamento da superclasse e especializar ele na sub.

Agora pense no caso das aves que não andam mas saltam, não podemos adicionar o método andar em animal por quê seria um problema para aves, porém, mamíferos andam, em sua maioria. Como resolver? Traits, poderíamos adicionar o método locomover, abstrato em animal, ou criar uma Trait Andar e usá-la apenas nos anomais que andam, por exemplo, pato é uma ave e anda.

Algo assim com o exemplo do comportamento de locomoção:

```php
Class Animal {
   function locomover(){...}

   function comer() {...}
}

Class Ave extends Animal {
   function comer() {
      parent::comer();
      // complemento da lógica
   }

   function voar() {...}

   function locomover() {
      $this->voar();
   }
}

Trait PodeAndar {
   function andar() {
      ...
   }
}

Class Pato() extends Ave {
   use PodeAndar; // automaticamente pato além de voar e locomover, agora possui o método andar também
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou dar uma olhada nas Trait's, para ver se consigo aproveitar.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando, uma resposta que encontrei no livro **Padrões de projeto**, capitulo 5 pagina 301, sobre o pattern **Template Method**, aonde é destacado no texto o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja talvez meu ponto de vista não esteja tão errado, no meu exemplo simplifiquei uma relação como vendas.

Comment: Releia com atenção a resposta do Maniero. Dar um nome "vendas" a uma classe é uma atitude incoerente do ponto de vista de orientação a objetos. Quais são as responsabilidades dessa classe? O que essa classe se propõe a fazer? O trecho que colocou sobre _template method_ pressupõe que o padrão, como todos os padrões, esteja sendo usado no lugar certo e do jeito certo, isso não é necessariamente verdade se o objetivo da classe vendas não estiver claro. Talvez devesse injetar no PDV (passar via construtor) uma instância responsável pelo acesso a dados (mas com um nome melhor que "vendas").