# Corrigir JButton que está executando 2 eventos

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Tenho uma aplicação onde em um JFrame eu crio novos registros para tabela mysql, e em um outro eu retorno um select numa `JTable` com todos os registros criados.

Tenho um botão alterar, que quando seleciono uma linha do JTable e clico nele,  abre uma instancia do primeiro JFrame para criar registros, já setando as informações da linha selecionada.

Eu consigo atualizar, aparece o JoptionPane informando que foi atualizado, só que a aplicação também executa o código de inserção, criando assim um novo registro. O problema é que não consigo desvincular os actionListener do botão, então ele executa primeiramente o código de atualizar e depois de inserir.

Código do botão para criar registros:

```
public class teste3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JButton jbutton;
    public teste3() {
        initComponents();

        this.jbutton = jButton1;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(173, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(121, 121, 121)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "oi");
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(teste3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(teste3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(teste3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(teste3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new teste3().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

código para atualizar:

```
public class Teste2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    teste3 teste3 = new teste3();

    public Teste2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(173, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(128, 128, 128)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(148, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        teste3 teste3 = new teste3();
        teste3.setVisible(true);

        teste3.jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(teste3, "oi2");
            }
        });
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Teste2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Sem um **[mcve]** fica dificil ajudar. Você nao é novo no site, e eu sempre peço um mcve e vc ignora, como espera ajuda de alguem se nem voce mesmo ajuda a gente a te ajudar?

Comment: @Articuno, acho que agora consegui explicar melhor o meu problema. As ações dos dois botões são realizadas. Quero que apenas uma seja realizada.

Comment: Ta vendo? Foi tao dificil assim criar um **[mcve]**? Vou tentar reproduzir o codigo para ver se localizo o erro.

Comment: Você chegou a ler minha resposta? Por que, por coincidencia, eu já citei qual o erro e como corrigir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O exemplo adicionado só reforça o que eu já havia mencionado, de que o causador do problema é você aplicar um listener dentro de outro listener. Neste trecho da classe `Teste2`:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    teste3 teste3 = new teste3();
    teste3.setVisible(true);

    teste3.jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(teste3, "oi2");
        }
    });
}
```

Você inicia a outra tela e ao mesmo tempo, adiciona um novo listener ao botao desta nova tela.

Aqui há dois erros: um eu já mencionei, que é adicionar listener dentro de outro sem nenhum tipo de controle, e o outro erro é a violação de encapsulamento. Se não souber o que é isso, recomendo que leia [**esta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214767/qual-a-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-encapsulamento-e-polimorfismo) daqui mesmo do site para entender melhor.

O que ocorre, na verdade, não é a execução duas vezes do mesmo método, e sim a execução dos dois listeners que você aplica ao botão, pois na classe `teste3` você já havia adicionado um listener.

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }

...

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "oi");
}
```

Como corrigir? Simples! Cada janela deve ser responsável por seus componentes e pelos eventos que dentro dela ocorrem, então basta separar a responsabilidade de cada janela dentro da classe própria e não ficar alterando componente de uma janela na outra, como eu ja mencionei, isso viola encapsulamento e é uma péssima pratica de programação, quando se faz sem ter noção do que isso signifique ou das consequências que isso pode causar.

Se `jbutton1` pertence a classe `teste3`, deixe tudo que for evento somente nesta classe, e aplique apenas um `ActionListner`, pois dificilmente você precisará aplicar mais de um listener do mesmo tipo ao mesmo componente, particularmente nunca vi esse tipo de necessidade.

Sugiro que sempre inicie pelos [tutoriais do java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html), e também há a tag [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) aqui no site com muito conteúdo, pois se você quer mexer com a api *swing* mas sequer tem noção de como ela funciona, você vai enfrentar esse tipo de dificuldade e continuar fazendo esse tipo de implementação prejudicial a sua aplicação.