# Sobrecarga de método é polimorfismo?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo, sobrecarga

Estou com dificuldades de entender o conceito de polimorfismo em Java, li dois artigos do mesmo portal agora e me confundi mais, pois para minha interpretação eles se contradizem:

Trecho 1:

> " A sobrecarga de métodos (overload) é um conceito do polimorfismo que consiste basicamente em criar variações de um mesmo método, ou seja, a criação de dois ou mais métodos com nomes totalmente iguais em uma classe. A Sobrecarga permite que utilizemos o mesmo nome em mais de um método contanto que suas listas de argumentos sejam diferentes para que seja feita a separação dos mesmos."

https://www.devmedia.com.br/sobrecarga-e-sobreposicao-de-metodos-em-orientacao-a-objetos/33066

Trecho 2:

> " Polimorfismo é o princípio pelo qual duas ou mais classes derivadas de uma mesma superclasse podem invocar métodos que têm a mesma identificação, assinatura, mas comportamentos distintos, especializados para cada classe derivada, usando para tanto uma referência a um objeto do tipo da superclasse. O overload não é um tipo de polimorfismo, pois com overload a assinatura do método obrigatoriamente tem que ter argumentos diferentes, requisito que fere o conceito de Polimorfismo citado acima "
>   https://www.devmedia.com.br/encapsulamento-polimorfismo-heranca-em-java/12991

Então, sobrecarga de método é polimorfismo também?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as diferenças entre overriding e overloading no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189895/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Quando e por que devemos usar polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25100/28595)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigos...então pra aproveitar o tópico: hoje eu tive uma prova de conceitos de OO em Java, de assinalar, e uma questão a qual eu vim pra casa encucado era sobre o polimorfismo, a afirmação era que para ser polimorfismo tem que haver sobrecarga de método, pus como errada, então acertei né? Já que se houver só sobrescrita de método já é polimorfismo, correto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral, publicações, algumas até bem famosas, podem errar. Na verdade, todos podem. Tem muito material errado por aí, muitas vezes apenas por algum descuido.

Note que nesse caso são artigos diferentes de autores diferentes, então é normal que cada um tenha uma visão, aqui você verá outra(s). Nem sempre uma está errada só porque é diferente de outra. Não nesse caso, mas também é bom sempre olhar a data da publicação. E as credenciais do autor, porque o papel e HTML aceitam tudo.

> A sobrecarga de métodos (*overload*) é um conceito do polimorfismo que consiste basicamente em criar variações de um mesmo método, ou seja, a criação de dois ou mais métodos com nomes totalmente iguais em uma classe. A Sobrecarga permite que utilizemos o mesmo nome em mais de um método contanto que suas listas de argumentos sejam diferentes para que seja feita a separação dos mesmos

Pode ser um polimorfismo *ad-hoc*, mas as pessoas não costumam usar este termo no dia a dia.

O texto é confuso e incompleto, mas está tecnicamente correto. O artigo como um todo está cheio coisas estranhas e até mesmo claramente incorretas nos detalhes.

> Polimorfismo é o princípio pelo qual duas ou mais classes derivadas de uma mesma superclasse podem invocar métodos que têm a mesma identificação, assinatura, mas comportamentos distintos, especializados para cada classe derivada, usando para tanto uma referência a um objeto do tipo da superclasse. O overload não é um tipo de polimorfismo, pois com overload a assinatura do método obrigatoriamente tem que ter argumentos diferentes, requisito que fere o conceito de Polimorfismo citado acima

Porque será que precisa duas classes pelo menos? Não basta uma? Já começou mal. `usando para tanto uma referência a um objeto do tipo da superclasse` parece confuso ou só incorreto mesmo. Eu gosto mais dessa escola de considerar o *overload* como algo diferente, embora teoricamente até seja, na prática não usamos esse termo.

Ele deveria citar onde que há a exigência que a assinatura deve ser igual para ser polimorfismo. Tenho a impressão que ele não consegue, isso não tem fundamento. Digo assim porque ele está fundamentando. Se fosse só citar, ok, se for só para usar termos diferentes para cada mecanismo, que é bom para ficar mais fácil de comunicar a intenção.

O artigo tem outras coisas meio "soltas".

> para ser polimorfismo tem que haver sobrecarga de método, pus como errada, então acertei né?

Há controvérsias. A sobrecarga clássica é horizontal, é ter métodos com mesmo nome, mas com [assinaturas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Há quem chame o polimorfismo de sobrecarga vertical onde um método idêntico na assinatura tem comportamento diferente dependendo do nível da herança que ele está. Mas eu prefiro chamar só de polimorfismo para evitar confusão. E ele pode ocorrer de forma dinâmica, o mais comum, ou estática em geral com [*templates* ou *generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101).

Eu não confiaria nos artigos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas!

Comment: @DouglasdaSilva dê uma olhada no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: "*Porque será que precisa duas classes pelo menos? Não basta uma?*". Pensei a mesma coisa quando estava lendo a pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Nossa, eu também fiquei pensando nessa questão enquanto aprendia o Java.
Fortaleço a resposta do colega acima, que todos podem errar e quem tem visões diferentes. Vou dar minha visão, onde o próprio conceito de polimorfismo me ajuda a ver o que acontece.
"Polimorfismo é quando um mesmo método pode se comportar de diversas formas, onde a aplicação decide." em minhas palavras.
Assim tanto a herança que sobrescreve o funcionamento de um método quanto a sobrecarga numa mesma classe podem ser chamadas de polimorfismo.

Entretanto a linguagem java sobrescreve o polimorfismo na mesma classe (em especial os construtores) com um conceito de sobrecarga criado por eles. Possivelmente devido as suas evoluções históricas, e suas implementações contínuas.

Resumo:
É como se as linguagens herdassem as informações da classe pai de o que é polimorfismo, mais abstrata. E sobrescreverem algo para ficar melhor ou mais claro conceito quando necessário. E nesse caso o java tenha escolhido criar bem claramente o conceito de sobrecarga que poderia se passar apenas pelo conceito abstrato de polimorfismo geral, mas que no seu mundo específico achou que faz sentido mudar um pouco para um caso mais específico com outro nome.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).