# o que é sobrecarga e sobreposição de métodos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Em programação orientada a  objetos é possível fazer sobrecarga de métodos. O que é e para que serve a sobrecarga de métodos?

Comment: User, acredito que sua questão já foi respondida [ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310083/sobrecarga-de-m%C3%A9todo-%C3%A9-polimorfismo ]

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Sobrecarga de método é polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310083/18246)