# Polimorfismo paramétrico e sobrecarga em Java e C++

Tags: java, c++, terminologia, genéricos, polimorfismo

A seguinte questão caiu no concurso do IFSP:

> Nas linguagens de programação Java e C++, o polimorfismo paramétrico é
>   materializado, respectivamente, pelas funcionalidades e/ou
>   características:
>  (A) Genéricos e *Templates*.
>  (B) Genéricos e
>   Sobrecarga de Operadores.
>  (C) Sobrecarga e *Templates*.
>  (D)
>   Anotações e Sobrescrita.

No gabarito preliminar a opção correta é a "A".

Marquei a letra "C", pois entendo que o polimorfismo paramétrico (possibilidade de definir várias funções com mesmo nome, mas com parâmetros diferentes) e mesmo que polimorfismo por sobrecarga.

1 - Qual a diferença entre polimorfismo paramétrico e polimorfismo por sobrecarga?)

2 - Em C++ *Templates* é a forma de se definir polimorfismo paramétrico?

3 - Qual a forma de se definir polimorfismo paramétrico em Java? Seria *generics*? Neste caso, poderíamos traduzir a palavra e disser que é genéricos?

Comment: Talvez [Isso te ajude](https://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~jefersson/cursos/dcc052/Aula10.pdf)

Comment: Se tu entendes inglês, [isso também pode ajudar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311638/c-parametric-polymorphism)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A correta é A mesmo.

> 1 - Qual a diferença entre polimorfismo paramétrico e polimorfismo por sobrecarga?)

Veja [Sobrecarga de método é polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310083/101). E [Aparece "+ 3 overloads" no Visual Studio - O que seria isso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101). Também respondi em [Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Ambos são resolvidos em tempo de compilação e são usados em tipagem estática. Mas são mecanismos diferentes. O paramétrico gera código novo de acordo com o tipo usado e pode haver uma explosão de geração ou acaba criando um certo dinamismo usando `void *`, apesar de manter a segurança de tipos na superfície. A sobrecarga sempre é feita uma escolha entre métodos já existentes.

O paramétrico é muito mais poderoso e pode ser usado em diversas circunstâncias (ele chega ser [*Turing complete*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)), em especial quando usa *template*, já a sobrecarga só pode ocorrer em métodos.

> 2 - Em C++ Templates é a forma de se definir polimorfismo paramétrico?

Sim. Pode ver em [Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101).

> 3 - Qual a forma de se definir polimorfismo paramétrico em Java? Seria generics? Neste caso, poderíamos traduzir a palavra e disser que é genéricos?

Sim. Conforme mostrado no *link* acima. Geralmente quando traduzimos é como genéricos assim como *templates* são gabaritos, mas na verdade usamos mais o termo em inglês mesmo. Veja mais em [O que é programação genérica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101).

Ou seja, se consultasse mais o SOpt poderia ter acertado :) Eu vivo falando isso pra todo mundo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não seria o caso de marcar como duplicata?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam eu estava colocando a diferença que não tem em lugar algum.

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei ali, nos comentários, links para fontes que falam sobre polimorfismo paramétrico. Sobrecarga se refere ao polimorfismo "regular", por isso a opção C está incorreta.

Polimorfismo paramétrico significa que um tipo pode ser parametrizado por outro tipo - por exemplo, as coleções em Java (`List`, por exemplo) podem ser compostas por objetos de diferentes tipos. Quando tu declaras um `ArrayList`, tu sempre defines um tipo `ArrayList<ClassType>`. De semelhante forma, tu podes parametrizar em C++, com templates.