# O que é Monomorphization?

Tags: c++, terminologia, genéricos, polimorfismo, rust

Estava lendo essa [postagem](https://endler.dev/2020/rust-compile-times/) e me deparei com esse termo *monomorphization*

Gostaria de saber:

- Qual seu significado?
- Quando esse processo ocorre?
- Qual o ganho/perda de performance que é obtido por esse processo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por vezes escrevemos códigos polimórficos. Um dos polimorfismos mais usados é a virtualização onde o ponteiro decidirá em tempo de execução o que fazer de forma especializada, mas o código escrito é genérico, você diz que precisa fazer uma operação que um objeto base é capaz, mas objetos derivados dele também sabem fazer e podem fazer de um jeito mais específico. Não vou falar muito nisso, veja [outra resposta se não domina o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

Mas existe outro polimorfismo muito interessante que é o paramétrico. [Alguns bem poderosos como do C++, outros menos como de Java ou C# que são *generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101). Sugiro ler mais em [Polimorfismo paramétrico e sobrecarga em Java e C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360431/101).

Eles podem ser usados de várias formas, entre elas exatamente o que está dizendo acima. Você escreve um código genérico, um gabarito para o código real e na execução será executado o código real específico para a situação. A diferença na decisão se executará um método base ou derivado é que este mecanismo permite que a escolha seja feita em tempo de compilação.

Se isso for feito, a monomorfização é realizada. Note que alguns mecanismos, especialmente de *generics*, não fazem isso sempre que tem uma parametrização de tipos e a decisão do que usar pode ser realizada em tempo de execução, então o código continua polimórfico no executável.

A monomorfização é pegar aquele código escrito polimórfico e transformá-lo em um código monomórfico, portanto um código de podia ter várias formas e passa ter uma forma especializada para cada situação usada.

Por exemplo, se o código de uma classe é polimórfico e ele aceita qualquer coisa que seja comparável (ele tem capacidade de comparação entre objetos), portanto o que vai usar ali só precisa chamar uma comparação, o objeto precisa ser capaz de fazer isso. E vamos dizer que você chamou aquilo que é polimórfico em três situações, com um `int`, com uma `String` e com um `Date`. O compilador criará três métodos iguais àquele escrito, cada um desses métodos usará um desses tipos para fazer a comparação.

Isso é bem interessante porque ele não tem a virtualização, não tem que decidir em tempo de execução o que fazer, fica mais rápido e pode até permitir certas otimizações.

Mas nem sempre é bom. Vamos dizer que você usou esse método polimórfico em 200 tipos diferentes. Será gerado 200 métodos diferentes.

Vou comparar com um código que todos entendem fácil:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) print(i);
```

é o mesmo que:

```
print(0)
print(1)
```

De fato um compilador que faz otimizações provavelmente transformará o primeiro no segundo e será mais rápido.

Mas e se o código for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) print(i);
```

compensa fazer o mesmo?

E se for assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user_entry; i++) print(i);
```

entendeu que tem uma variável que só se sabe em tempo de execução, né? Dá para otimizar, mesmo que o valor seja 0, 1, 2 ou outro baixo?

> Qual seu significado?

O ato de transformar um código genérico polimórfico em um código monomórfico.

> Quando esse processo ocorre?

No C++, durante a compilação sempre.

> Qual o ganho/perda de performance que é obtido por esse processo?

O de não precisar da [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para acessar um método e otimizações possíveis por causa disso. Perde ficar com um executável grande demais.

Exemplo real:

```
template <class T>
    T max(T a, T b) { return (a > b ? a : b); }
```

Quando chamar assim:

```
max(1, 2)
```

o compilador gerará um método assim:

```
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b ? a : b); }
```

E para cada tipo que for consumido gerará um método assim. Aquele método do `template`, que é polimórfico por definição, não existirá nunca, ele é só um gabarito para criar os métodos reais que são monomórficos.

Note que esse tipo de código é antigo para o C++ e daria erro em objetos que não podem fazer uma comparação, hoje normalmente usaria um [conceito](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints) para restringir que tipo pode ser usado ali e ficar mais robusto, mas isso é outro assunto.

Sem a monomorfização teria que fazer algo assim:

```
void *max(void *a, void *b) { return (*a > *b ? *a : *b); }
```

E aí o uso:

```
*(max(&1, &2))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/Monomorphization.cpp).