# O que é early binding e late binding?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, compilação

Além da tradução aceita dos termos, o que eles querem dizer? Por que eles existem e são importantes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos começar falando sobre *binding* que significa vinculação, ou seja, algo que relaciona uma coisa com outra e as mantém ligadas de alguma forma.

Estamos falando do tempo que algo é resolvido, sendo os mais comuns, mas não únicos, o tempo de compilação (*early binding* - vinculação imediata?), também chamado de estático, ou ainda o tempo de execução (*late binding* - vinculação tardia?), também chamado de dinâmico.

Qualquer linguagem pode ter ambos em seu sistema de tipos e outras operações, mas o primeiro é mais comum nas linguagens ditas estáticas e o segundo nas dinâmicas.

Geralmente estamos falando de quando um método ou função é resolvido. Ou seja, sobre que tipo de dado ele estará vinculado. É uma forma de *calling convention*.

Então qualquer decisão do que chamar (fazer o *lookup*) por *early binding* pega as informações que estão disponíveis durante a compilação e decide exatamente o que deve ser chamado. Ao contrário do *late binding* que considera que você não tem todas as informações necessárias e só durante a execução pode tomar essa decisão.

Obviamente que *late* é menos eficiente que *early*, e pode ser menos robusto. Mas em flexibilidade inverte a situação e tem vantagem para algo que cobra um preço.

Linguagens que costumam ser mais estáticas precisam de um mecanismo, como [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101), para ter o *late binding* mais poderoso. Elas podem ter alguma forma de *late binding* direto na linguagem. Um tipo de polimorfismo é assim.

Quando você chama um método/função com um tipo de dado que aceita herança pode ser que o que você está passando é um tipo herdado e não o original que espera ali. Então a linguagem tem algum mecanismo para saber que tipo está sendo usado (geralmente uma *vtable*) que decide o que deve executar. Esta é uma forma de *late binding*, só durante a execução ele pode decidir o que fazer.

Note que a decisão não acontece com um `if` (poderia ser), ele ocorre através de uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

No [polimorfismo paramétrico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360431/101) ([*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101)) a decisão acontece na compilação, já se sabe o que usar antes, por isso pode gerar um código extra para cada tipo usado na chamada.

Na verdade, isso acontece mais com [*templates*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101). Com *generics* pode ter uma "otimização" que faz com que vire só uma indireção mesmo (não vou entrar no mérito disso aqui). E tem casos que o *binding* ocorre no meio do caminho, nem na compilação, nem na execução, ocorre durante o processo de [JITting](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), que alguns vão considerar como uma forma de compilação, então seria *early binding* também.

A maioria das chamadas de métodos/funções normais podem ter o *early binding* se o tipo específico já é conhecido (linguagens de tipagem dinâmica nunca é conhecido).

É possível programar sem saber dos termos, mas sabendo o fará com mais consciência e pode fazer melhor. De alguma forma você sempre está usando pelo menos um deles.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).