# Como retornar os valores de uma List<> em C#

Tags: c#, .net, lista, classes

Tenho uma classe `Funcionario` que tem como atributos: `CPF`, `Nome` e `Salario`.

Eu tenho que criar uma quantidade X de instancias desta classe em uma `List<>` e após isso, retornar para o usuário os valores desta lista. Com o código que criei eu não obtive os valores das propriedades de cada instância, apenas o *namespace* e a classe.

```
aumento_funcionario.funcionario
```

Gostaria de saber o porquê disso. Segue meu código.

```
//Código da classe Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace aumento_funcionarios
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Quantos funcionários serão cadastrados? ");
            int qtde_cadastros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            List<funcionario> Lista = new List<funcionario>();

            for (int i = 0; i < qtde_cadastros; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dados do " + (i + 1) + "º funcionário: ");
                Console.Write("CPF: ");
                int cpf = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Nome: ");
                string nome = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Salário: ");
                double salario = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Lista.Add(new funcionario(cpf, nome, salario));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Lista[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}




//Código classe Funcionarios
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;

    namespace aumento_funcionarios
    {
        class funcionario
        {
            public int CPF;
            public string Nome;
            public double Salario { get; private set; }

            public funcionario (int cpf, string nome, double salario)
            {
                this.CPF = cpf;
                this.Nome = nome;
                this.Salario = salario;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Acredito que com as respostas abaixo você já deve ter compreendido o seu engano em encontrado uma solução que lhe atenda. Mas por convenção da linguagem, as suas classes devem começar com uma letra maíuscula, então renomeie para `Funcionario` https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229043(v%3dvs.100)

Comment: Depois, eu não recomendaria você utilizar o tipo inteiro para armazenar um CPF, se ele não começar com 0 ele provavelmente já será um `long` e os que começarem vão dar dificultar a sua posterior consulta

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, @LeandroAngelo. Como o `int` neste caso supria a minha necessidade e no momento eu não estou preocupado com a performance do meu código então eu acabei usando o `int` mesmo. Mas conforme eu for avançando eu vou escolher os tipos de variáveis com mais atenção.

Comment: Eu também tenho que estudar mais sobre os padrões camelCase e PascalCase. Adotar um padrão ainda no início dos meus estudos será fundamental mais para a frente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você pede para escrever na console a lista de funcionários e uma vez que funcionários não é um tipo simples, e sim um objeto composto, o compilador não consegue imprimir ele da forma que você quer, fiz uma modificação no seu código de forma em que funcionará a impressão, depois, seguindo a logica, você pode modificar como for melhor para você. Segue o código:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Quantos funcionários serão cadastrados? ");
        int qtde_cadastros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        List<funcionario> Lista = new List<funcionario>();

        for (int i = 0; i < qtde_cadastros; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dados do " + (i + 1) + "º funcionário: ");
            Console.Write("CPF: ");
            int cpf = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Nome: ");
            string nome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Salário: ");
            double salario = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Lista.Add(new funcionario(cpf, nome, salario));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Lista[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
}

class funcionario
    {
        public int CPF;
        public string Nome;
        public double Salario { get; private set; }

        public funcionario (int cpf, string nome, double salario)
        {
            this.CPF = cpf;
            this.Nome = nome;
            this.Salario = salario;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "funcionario: " + this.CPF + " " + this.Nome + " " +this.Salario + "\n";
        }
    }
```

}

O que eu fiz foi sobrescrever o método de escrita do objeto funcionário de forma em que quando chamado imprime os atributos. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Entendi. Agradeço sua ajuda. Tenho que entender melhor como funciona essa sobrescrita.

Comment: O bom de sobrescrever o `ToString` é que você ganha uma melhor visualização quando está em modo de debug olhando para as instâncias do objeto.

Comment: Sugiro que leia essa pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/60398            Sei que é em java, mas o conceito é o mesmo

Comment: O `ToString()` Não deve ser usado para isto. É um erro comum que as pessoas cometem porque parece fácil resolver com ele, mas sua função é outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101

Comment: Bom se não quiser utilizar o método ToString() crie um método na classe para fazer essa impressão. Mas Controle ela na classe funcionário, assim caso algum dia você queria modificar a classe, tem que corrigir o método de impressão somente la.

Comment: Não faça isto também, porque a impressão é algo contextual, em cada situação desejará uma forma diferente, isto não faz o menor sentido. É até possível ter uma outra classe para cuidar de algumas dessas coisas, mas mesmo isso não faz sentido porque o você não considerará o contexto exato em cada caso. Isto é algo que algumas pessoas ensinaram errado e aí as pessoas repetem como se fosse verdade. Em geral quem inventou isso era um acadêmico e não um engenheiro que programa no dia a dia, e pena que outras apenas seguem receitas de bolo sem questionar.

Comment: Criar varias classes de tipos de impressão genericas e um Factory para gerir o utilizo delas nesse caso me parece um pouco com o caso de utilizar uma bazuca para matar uma formiga...

Comment: E criar todas impressões possíveis em uma classe parece querer usar um fusca para táxi, van escolar, transporte de água, sacos de feijão, fazer patrulhamento, ir até a esquina, levar combustível para outros veículos, fazer acrobacias, utilizar como barricada, etc. Faça um sistema de verdade assim, coloque todo tipo de impressão necessárias nele e depois venha me contar como foi. Por isso que eu sempre falo para as pessoas pararem de "programar orientado a objeto", em geral está criando monstrengos que "sabem" fazer tudo o que o sistema precisa, e complica a manutenção demais.E vira zona,sempre

Answer (score 7):

Tem vários problemas no código, alguns apenas de estilo. O maior é que está tentando converter algo que não é garantido que pode ser convertido e isso quebrará a aplicação se a digitação for errada. O certo é verificar antes de usar. Eu apenas encerrei a aplicação para simplificar, mas você pode emitir uma mensagem de erro e pedir novamente a digitação até que se entrado um valor válido. Em código real as pessoas criam códigos que fazem isso em cada item e colocam em função para uso fácil.

Note que mudei várias coisas no código, como a forma de imprimir, os nomes das coisas, e o uso do `foreach` no lugar do `for`. Ele deve ser a preferência, até que só o `for` resolva. Usei nomes dentro do [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Se usou uma propriedade em um campo da classe, porque não usar em todos? Ou porque não usar campo em todas se usou em dois deles? Mantenha um padrão. Inclusive manter o padrão de maiúsculo e minúsculo correto, que eu deixei errado.

Você estava mandando imprimir a lista. Ela não tem um meio de impressão automático dela que sai tudo como imagina. Tem infinitas formas de imprimir um lista, você tem que montar isso item por item. E mesmo dentro do item também tem muitas formas de imprimir cada membro do item da lista, então tem que lidar com isso. Até a lista estava pegando cada item, mas não cada membro.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Quantos funcionários serão cadastrados? ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var quantidade)) return;
        var lista = new List<Funcionario>();
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
            WriteLine($"Dados do {(i + 1)}º funcionário: ");
            Write("CPF: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var cpf)) return;
            Write("Nome: ");
            var nome = ReadLine();
            Write("Salário: ");
            if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var salario)) return;
            lista.Add(new Funcionario(cpf, nome, salario));
            WriteLine();
        }
        foreach (var item in lista) WriteLine($"CPF: {item.Cpf} - Nome: {item.Nome} - Salário: {item.Salario}");
    }
}

public class Funcionario {
    public int Cpf;
    public string Nome;
    public double Salario { get; private set; }
    public Funcionario (int cpf, string nome, double salario) {
        Cpf = cpf;
        Nome = nome;
        Salario = salario;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jvIulx). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQy6av). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AccessMemberConsole.cs).

Comment: Meu código ainda é bem amador, é verdade, mas não há jeito melhor para aprender do que tentar e errar. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: E aprendeu agora?

Comment: Bom um vez que você esta aprendendo tenho que dizer que esse modo de impressão de objeto não é modular, caso venha modificada a classe funcionário você tem que modificar pontualmente em todo o código onde esta imprimindo, eu sugiro a modificar a impressão do objeto na classe

Comment: @UmProgramador E usar `ToString()` para isto não é correto, porque em cada contexto a impressão deve ser de um jeito. Mesmo ter vários métodos para impressão na classe fere o Princípio da Responsabilidade Única. A impressão de dados não deve ser responsabilidade da própria classe, isto é algo externo. Alias quase todo programador falha na modelagem nisso. E modular é criar módulos e não amontoar tudo em uma classe. Cada um fazendo sua parte. Eu sugiro você entender melhor o motivo das coisas e não repetir falácias sobre desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: Bom, implemente um software grande utilizando esse tipo de impressão e depois de anos, de milhões de linhas de código com impressão assim, o cliente te pede pra modificar a classe fazendo com que esse método seja errado. Qual refatoração vai ser menos custosa. Se você se pôs tão didático porque não criou um sistema para gerir essa impressão e o colocou como resposta da pergunta... Deixo aqui meu comentário e não quero prolongar essa discussão pois foge do contexto

Comment: A desnecessidade de refatoração é sempre a mais barata. Se não tentar amontoar tudo em uma classe não precisa refatorar nada. Modularizar é exatamente colocar em módulos separados para não ter que mexer onde não deve. E o cliente não pede pra mexer em classe alguma, ele diz a necessidade dele, e você vai lá e muda o que tem que mudar. E não fere o O do SOLID se estiver separado. EU fiz exatamente oque tem que ser feito,deixar o consumidor pegar os dados que o objeto deve prover e fazer a impressão como ele precisa.Quem vai imprimir é responsável por formatar a impressão,este é o módulo correto

Answer (score 1):

Como a lista não é de um tipo simples, como string, int e etc...é preciso imprimir todos os atributos da lista.

No caso, ficaria assim:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Count; i++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(Lista[i].Cpf);
      Console.WriteLine(Lista[i].Nome);
      Console.WriteLine(Lista[i].Salario );
 }
```

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Como já mencionado, você deve exibir cada propriedade do seu objeto `Funcionario` da lista.

Pode utilizar o método `ForEach` para exibir, acaba ficando mais simples.

```
Lista.ForEach(funcionario =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(funcionario.Cpf);
            Console.WriteLine(funcionario.Nome);
            Console.WriteLine(funcionario.Salario);
        });
```

Comment: Isso não é LINQ. [É um método de `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Obrigado por avisar, ao fazer a resposta eu alterei o exemplo e esqueci de alterar a descrição!